# Compose a song, line by line

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, answer-chaining

It's time for CGCC to demonstrate our musical talent! In this challenge, you're going to compose songs while keeping your byte count as small as possible.

On Day 0, multiple answerers will post a function or program that outputs nothing/an empty string. They will also give a single line that next day's answers must output. More lines will be added to that line later, gradually building up a song. I'm not starting off Day 0 myself because letting multiple people answer will allow for more variety later.

On Day 1, answerers will choose an answer from Day 0. They will post a function or program that outputs the line from the Day 0 answer. This will be the song for the next answer. Like on Day 0, Day 1 answerers will also give a single line that next day's answers must add anywhere to their song.

On Day `i`, answerers will choose an answer from Day `i-1` with partial song `s` and line `l`. They can now insert `l` between any two lines in `s` or put it at the start or end of `s`. This will now yield a new partial song that each must write a function or program to output. Again, answerers will also give a line for next day's answers to add to their partial song.

## Rules

**The rules have been changed, please see the bolded parts below.** Sorry for the inconvenience.

- New lines can be put between other lines, at the start of the song, or at the end of the song.
- Lines may be repeated.
- Lines must be at least 20 characters and at most 100 characters.
- You may have trailing spaces at the end of each line when printing the song.
- **You may have multiple answers on a single day and you may answer on consecutive days, but you cannot continue from your answer on a consecutive day.**
- This isn't a hard rule, but if you take your line from a song, please link to it.
- The day changes at midnight UTC+0.
- Your score is the average length, in bytes, of all your answers (not including answers on Day 0), **divided by the number of answers you have posted** (this is a change from before, but the objective is still the same - make your answer as short as possible).

### It is currently Day 19.

## Examples

Note: These examples are just to show the format of each answer; they are not good examples of the kinds of songs you should write, as they lack creativity.

#### Day 0. Python, 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://www.google.com)

Line for next day: `Superman got nothing on me` (from [One Call Away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Call_Away_(Charlie_Puth_song)))

Song:

#### Day 1. Foobarbaz, 7 bytes

```
DOSTUFF
```

[Try it online!](https://www.google.com)

**[Previous answer](https://linktopreviousanswer)**

Line for next day: `I can eat more bananas than him`

Song:

```
Superman got nothing on me
```

#### Day 2. Foobarbaz, 11 bytes

```
DOMORESTUFF
```

[Try it online!](https://www.google.com)

**[Previous answer](https://linktopreviousanswer)**

Line for next day: `And I'm never gonna give you up` (modified from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ))

Song:

```
Superman got nothing on me
I can eat more bananas than him
```

#### Day 3. somelanguage, 3 bytes

```
foo
```

[Try it online!](https://www.google.com)

**[Previous answer](https://linktopreviousanswer)**

Line for next day: `That's the only thing that matters`

Song:

```
Superman got nothing on me
I can eat more bananas than him
And I'm never gonna give you up
```

A possible song for day 4 (note that the new line was inserted this time instead of being appended):

```
Superman got nothing on me
I can eat more bananas than him
That's the only thing that matters
And I'm never gonna give you up
```

Comment: I will offer a +100 bounty if there is an answer on each day, until Day 11, which is the next line from the [rickroll](https://genius.com/Rick-astley-never-gonna-give-you-up-lyrics) (i.e. up until the end of the chorus). I'll offer the bounty to the final line. If it continues past Day 11, I'll double the bounty for each day, until it reaches +500

Comment: "Your score is the average length, in bytes, of all your answers." - So if I answer only on day 0, I win by default?

Comment: @pxeger Err, yes. I'm sorry, I should have put more work into the scoring system.

Comment: Unless your answers consistently get shorter, it is wasteful to post multiple. I recommend a scoring method such as \$\frac{x̄}a\$, where \$x̄\$ is the arithmetic mean of the lengths of the answers and `a` is the number of answers. This more heavily weights the amount of answers you've posted, making it advantageous to post more.

Comment: What's the point of not being able to post on consecutive days?

Comment: @Makonede But a score for 0 bytes answer in day 0 still not get any improved then

Comment: @xigoi I'm not the OP, but I think the reason is so you can't pick strange lines like `zsh: string expected after -c` so you can pick up zero or one byte programs the next day. For example, if I posted an answer then said the next line was `Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined`, then if I were allowed to post answers on consecutive days I could simply post `_` then claim `this does output \`Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined\``.

Comment: @ophact And wouldn't it be enough to forbid directly continuing your own answer? I'd like to continue someone else's answer in the meantime…

Comment: IMO with the new scoring system you shouldn't be allowed to post multiple answers on the same day, as you could just farm points that way.

Comment: @Makonede Sorry, I don't see how you that would help you farm points

Comment: @user For example: if you find 5 different languages where `print("We're no strangers to love")` worked, you could post them all and get 7 points.

Comment: @Makonede You're right, but I'm counting on people to not abuse the rules like that intentionally. Edit: Actually, that's still 35 points.

Comment: @user No it isn't. The mean of all 5 answers would be 35, and with the new scoring system you divide that by the number of answers, and \$\frac{35}5=7\$.

Comment: @Makonede Whoops, you're right. Anyway, as I said in my comment above, people aren't supposed to abuse the rules like that. I could perhaps limit it to 3 answers per day, let me check in TNB to see if others agree.

Comment: I think people should comment on the songs they continue, so that newcomers can follow a link-trail.

Comment: @BenjaminWang People already link to the previous answer for that song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Day 18

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 881 bytes

```python
print("""side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
[ignore everything before this line]
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling""")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVNLi9swEL7rV3zJJQk4e@lpjwtliw99QAtlKT0o9thSI2uCHmv869OR620TmrZQ25onfDOe@XSakmH/6nw@BevTdr1eR9sSEqPo6kK@xNR7s8/7ReDS2WfUmwGdds76Xr1mj5HgeQTngF5P0KeTDuQqPGq425/6ZAijIXIRApDEO@SInhE4@xZazmxV/wyoOmFkv0k4EBz7HhNpg22Ru@qPjvrIaHRqzFT91DZtImJuDPQSQxRA9cGRjoT2qsr2yt2pB/33x6zU9o121hHvsBgVboQWA4@214HxVvfedrbh/fKq@3scOCVHMrtOGqDwMsNRllLh97x6J7gTZ/kr6fkOTxQr1MW7w/@kqgt7pepOrBRkgL/EnEIrdDtWV@pGdyv1xfaeA4GeKQhVhVeS6EpEnAghGn1Vn2kTCtEQU9C@pxALWR0/k3qSJo@FgmUIIRfswo/IsjPU6gFddg4ND4NNA/my5tHoNBO5lDuWitzNOCNn15bN9pR@lO8CD4I3gQVeKJ4nVeNbjsI77b1GIgEvczLSwXw3hNeCKNdsdz5/Bw)

Day 19: `Gotta make you understand` that we're taking this to the top this time.

Answer (score 12):

## Day 0. [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 5 bytes

```java
a->""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCoMwFEX3fsXDSaGG7mkdCx06OZYOrxrl2ZiE5EWQ4rengdrpXu453AkXrK1TZurfiWZnPcOUNxGZtBii6ZisEde9yIOLL00ddBpDgDuSgQ/sW2DkHIulHuZMypY9mfHxBPRjqLL4vznfDKtR@SP8lAYGuEDCuimKJKFdA6tZ2MjCZczlINA5vZanqpKwwZa@)

The line for tomorrow is `Baka mitai kodomo na no ne`.

thanks to caird for reminding me i don't need to submit a full program lol

Comment: [Right](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/M68ktSgtMTlVwbe6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0UhNzEzTyO4pCgzLz06NlGzurb2/38A). :P

Comment: @user oh, when i was trying that with an enum it was complaining about no main class. maybe cuz it couldn't find something to name the file as :P

Comment: Where's the next line?

Comment: @xigoi lol, whoops. thanks for pointing that out. thanks pxeger

Answer (score 11):

## Day 0. [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
⁸
```

[Try it on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)[l](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R447//wE)[ine!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

The line for tomorrow is `We're no strangers to love`

### How it works

`⁸` is a builtin for `[]` (the empty array), assuming no arguments are passed. Due to Jelly's printing, this displays nothing

Comment: lyxal's gonna be disappointed that they got beaten to this

Comment: It seems that you got outgolfed by Hexagony, of all languages. Try harder. :P

Comment: I suppose you know the rules?

Comment: @xigoi I guess Jelly isn't the golfiest at doing nothing :(

Comment: @Lyxal Yes, and so do you

Comment: Hope you all are fully committed because I suspect you're going to get this from many other guys...

Comment: Wouldn't `“` have been better for future days?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I don't think there's any restrictions on the characters that can't/must be used on later days, is there?

Comment: You're right, it seems not.

Comment: I am *very* disappointed that the TIO link does not link to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

Comment: @Delfad0r Hmm, does it? Maybe you should click it and see ;)

Comment: Take your upvote and get out

Answer (score 8):

## Day 0. [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 0 bytes

Nothing to it.

The line for tomorrow is `Baby shark doo doo doo-doo doo-doo`

Comment: That nearly earned you a downvote, that'll be stuck in my head all day :p

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Song lyrics were chosen *purely* for golfability and not at all for their potent earworm potential, of course ;) P.S. https://youtu.be/dV1WRVglQMs

Answer (score 8):

## Day 0, [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/Q8EAA)

Line for next day: `side to side, side, side to side`

Taken from [Revenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPJUBQd-PNM) by CaptainSparklez. Instead of the first line, I chose one that can be compressed well.

Comment: For those who missed the first line: `so we back in the mine, got our pickaxe swinging from side to side` (yes I quoted that from memory)

Comment: @Lyxal isn’t it `Creeper, oh man`? Aww I miss those times. Might learn a golfing language just to print this.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 35 bytes

```py
print("We're no strangers to love")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQyk8Vb0oVSEvX6G4pCgxLz21qFihJF8hJ78sVUnz/38A)

Line for next day: `You know the rules, and so do I`.

It begins.

Comment: -2 using Python 2: `print"We're no strangers to love"`

Answer (score 5):

## Day 0. [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) 1 byte

```
¤
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%A4&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Tomorrow's line is: `How ba-a-a-ad can I be? I'm just doing what comes naturally--` taken from [How Bad Can I be](https://genius.com/Ed-helms-how-bad-can-i-be-lyrics) from the Lorax.

Consequently, I now would like to be referred to as `The Lyx-ler` (a play on the name "the once-ler").

Comment: If you want to be referred to "The Lyx-ler", just change your name

Answer (score 5):

## Day 0, [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8DwQA)

Tomorrow's line is: `A B C Ch D E F G H I J K Ll L M N Ñ O P Q R Rr S T U V W X Y Z`
from [the Spanish alphabet song](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5ec3dg)

Comment: Whoops just realized I got L and Ll backwards, guess I'll leave it at this point though.

Answer (score 5):

## Day 0. [nameless language](https://github.com/bforte/nameless-lang), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vMTc1JLS7@DwQA)

Line for next day: `Juno was mad, He knew he'd been had, So he shot at the sun with a gun`, [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8sUC-dsW8A)

Comment: Ruler of everything. Very respectable

Answer (score 5):

## Day 0. [unsure](https://github.com/Radvylf/unsure), 0 bytes

Line for next day: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19`

Comment: What song is this?

Answer (score 4):

## Day 0. [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 5 bytes

```c
f(){}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O69n9mXolCbmJmnoYmVzWXAhAAha25av//S07LSUwv/q9bDgA)

Next line: `YOU ARE LIKELY TO BE EATEN BY A GRUE` [(MC Frontalot "It Is Pitch Dark")](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nigRT2KmCE&ab_channel=MCFrontalot)

Answer (score 4):

## Day 0, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5DwQA) <s>Link is to verbose version of code.</s>

Next: line: `Deck the halls with boughs of holly, Fa la la la la la la la la!` Optional comma between the fourth and fifth `la`.

Answer (score 4):

## Day 1. [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25 bytes

```
j", "[Kj" to ",J"side"JJK
```

[Try it here](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=j%22%2C+%22%5BKj%22+to+%22%2CJ%22side%22JJK&debug=0)

**[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224578/78186)**

Line for next day: `do you like my sword, sword, sword my diamond sword, sword`

The song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
```

Comment: @user whoops, sure thing

Comment: http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=j%22%2C+%22%5BKj%22+to+%22%2CJ%22slide%22JJK&debug=0

Answer (score 4):

## Day 1. [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `S`, 19 bytes

```
`⟇ɽ to``⟇ɽ,`ȮȮ$Ȯṫ_W
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=%60%E2%9F%87%C9%BD%20to%60%60%E2%9F%87%C9%BD%2C%60%C8%AE%C8%AE%24%C8%AE%E1%B9%AB_W&inputs=&header=&footer=)

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224578/77516)

Song:

`side to side, side, side to side`

Line for next day: `Tell me, tell me if you love me or not, love me or not, love me or not?` from [Maroon 5 - What Lovers Do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Wiio4KoGe8)

Answer (score 3):

## Day 0. [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 1 byte

```
@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//93@P8fAA)

Line for next day: `I'm only human after all` (from [Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_(Rag%27n%27Bone_Man_song)))

Answer (score 3):

## Day 0, [PHP](https://php.net/), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk//8HAA)

Next line: `I'd like to find out what reality I'm in` ([Night Verses "Phoenix IV: Levitation"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1js-01XnQY))

Nothing planned to reduce byte counts, just currently listening to this amazing album, it kinda have lyrics (voice samples), and I like that line

Answer (score 3):

## Day 1. Picolisp, <s>47</s> 42 bytes

```
(prin"Baby Shark doo doo doo-doo doo-doo")
```

---

#### Much more interesting, 47 byte version

```
(prin(text"Baby Shark @1@1@2@1@2@1""doo "'doo-]
```

---

Next lyric: `you're not JoKing, you're`

[Previous lyrics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224567/90614)

I'd also post the full song so far, but I don't want to accidentally read it myself.

Answer (score 3):

## Day 1, Deadfish~, 323 bytes

```
{{i}ddd}iiic{ddd}ddddc{iiiiii}ic{{d}iii}iic{{i}ddd}iiiiiicdddciicddddddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}dd}iiiicdddddc{{d}ii}ic{{i}ddd}ciiiciiiiic{d}c{{d}iii}iic{{i}dd}dciiiiiicdc{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}d}dddc{d}dddddc{d}iiic{ii}dc{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}dd}iic{d}dddcddddc{i}icdddc{i}iciiiiic{{d}i}ic{iiii}ic{ddd}ddddc{{i}ddd}c{{d}ii}iiic{{i}ddd}iiiciiiiic
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBJCsAwCHxRH1ViSz33KPN269oQEggZnEUNXSfd/D6HqgiDiMDMQxzYpSEcB1aT4OD0lLradfmEo3UlQ2t@DjNhOJcpRu09QKObtLmCDCBQDhogYlyyawnZwgu1GHLyADWCu8C5NJZv6Hl7g/UXyq/6AQ)

Song so far:
`I'd like to find out what reality I'm in`

Next line:
`We wish you a Merry Christmas and a happy New Year!`

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224562/compose-a-song-line-by-line/224584#224584)

Answer (score 3):

## Day 1, Javascript, 67 / 131

### Printing it, 67

```js
_=>`A B C Ch D E F G H I J K Ll L M N Ñ O P Q R Rr S T U V W X Y Z`
```

### More interesting but longer, 131

```js
_=>[...Array(30).keys()].map(i=>i^3?i^12?i^16?i^21?String.fromCharCode(65+i-(i>3)-(i>12)-(i>16)-(i>21)):'Rr':'Ñ':'Ll':'Ch').join` `
```

[Previous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224562/compose-a-song-line-by-line/224568#224568)

Next line: `Money money money, it must be funny, in a rich man's world` ([from here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETxmCCsMoD0))

Answer (score 3):

## Day 1, [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 28 bytes

```sh
<<Z
I'm only human after all
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxiaKy1M9VyE/L6dSIaM0NzFPITGtJLVIITEn5/9/AA)

Song so far:

```sh
I'm only human after all
```

Next line: `I'm only human after all` (yes, that's the same line repeated again - that's how the song goes...)

Answer (score 3):

## Day 1. [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 43 bytes

```
`λ… ba-a-a-ad λ‹ I be? I'm λ¾ °Ḋ λ⟨ †↲ ₀⅛--
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%CE%BB%E2%80%A6%20ba-a-a-ad%20%CE%BB%E2%80%B9%20I%20be%3F%20I%27m%20%CE%BB%C2%BE%20%C2%B0%E1%B8%8A%20%CE%BB%E2%9F%A8%20%E2%80%A0%E2%86%B2%20%E2%82%80%E2%85%9B--&inputs=&header=&footer=)

**[Previous Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224566/101522)**

Line for tomorrow: `If it's all right, then you're all wrong.` From [*I Know, You Know*](https://genius.com/The-friendly-indians-i-know-you-know-lyrics), a.k.a. the [*Psych*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psych) theme song, by The Friendly Indians

---

Song so far:

```
How ba-a-a-ad can I be? I'm just doing what comes naturally--
```

Comment: I upvoted this just for the choice of song :P

Answer (score 3):

## Day 1, [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 677 bytes

```
++++++++++[>++++++++++>+++++++++++>+++++>++++++>++++<<<<<-]>+.>+.+++.>>-.<<----.>>---.<++.<++.<.+++++.>>>.<<<--------.>++++.----.>>+++.---.<<<.>-.<+++.++++.>++++++.<-.>-.-----.+.+++++++.<-------.>>>.<<<+++++++.>>+.<-------.-.+++.>.>.<<<.>---.<------.>>>.<<<++++++.>>.<+.>---.>+.<<<.>>+++.<<-----------.>>--------.>.<+++++.+++.--------.<------.<.>+++++++++++++.<++++++++++.++.+++++++.>>>-----.<<<-.--------------------.>>>-.++.<<<++++++++++++++.>.<++++++.>--.<----------.>------.++++++.>>++++.<<<----------.>>.+++.<<++++++++++.>-.<-.>-----.-----.<++.>+++++++++++.------.+++++.----.-.<+.>>>++.<<<++++.--------.>-----.++.---.++++++++++++.+++.<++++++.++++++.----.-.------.++++++++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFLCkIxDDxQyJwg5CLiQgVBBBeC56/59TUVw/uk02Q6mV7fl8fr/rk9x6AjTrryllaubSEefFaCPbaGKsMQC0/tKwbGi@gyVCFZkVWBVkOlXgCN3mAl1JkQdjw7cyvRSZbkEzfCtcepD1rsfsy/NviCssD7vTiELdHHdJUiWzEn4U4u6BamG0dOawgtxnAH/CeiBKFEaOecEkI3pPfUf1mSs2w1igQ7I6fZ6R3Pq@yzoFOjTJaYZInEjxLUFW/ymy2gjW5Tb/AYXw)

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224562/compose-a-song-line-by-line/224570#224570)

Song so far:

```
eor;n84pej8btp;8boeiuhtopwa8h5por58hob8h5p29h5]-925-j]wgip4o[35iwoueou9[-0etdojfuotpog;kcjliuxiokjdl
```

Next line:

```
You are my SyntaxError, my only SyntaxError.
```

Makonede, maybe get some singing lessons?

*I learned brainfuck for this.*

Comment: Me? I have a [hit song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) with almost a billion views.

Comment: @Makonede Dammit I actually clicked that.

Answer (score 3):

## Day 2, PHP, follows [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224562/compose-a-song-line-by-line/224676#224676), 75 bytes

```php
<?=$a=side," to $a, $a, $a to $a
",$i='Oh-u',"-$i-$i $i-$i-Oh I'm falling";
```

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh I'm falling
```

Next line:

```
Na, na, na-na-na-na, na-na-na-na, hey Jude
```

From [Hey Jude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_MjCqQoLLA)

Answer (score 3):

## Day 14, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 450 bytes

```
⟦⪫Ｅ313…side to ×Ｉι⁴, ⟧Ｆ²⁺…Oh-u-⊗⁺ι⁶ “P➙⭆BＸ5↶÷ρ⦄⟧⁸A>ιZ›➙πα⊗σ*7¹´$⁹“ＢzＩ⊞³⌈”× la⁸“[¶²/;pv﹪ＨD⦃»ⅉδE4pＰf·⁹E”⪫Ｅ³… round and¹⁶,¦⸿It won't be long⪫Ｅ³ yeah (yeah)¦,⪫⪪“Z⧴aC¿Jy⌈←*üYlΦθd;hＡ⊗Ｕ±”¶¦ catchy⪫⟦⸿Please ¦ (¦)⸿A⟧don't be long×a³⁵⪫⪪“T⊞8⁻‖⟧e2ü"↑«℅γ“=βk²↨r⊟h‹⬤ＢY=⁰”¶¦Galileo…o-⁹⸿Ｆ²⁺× on the wall, ι”- ⊟d⌈Pï⌊;∕1/↖⍘”⸿⪫Ｅ..,!⁺⁺×No, you can't. ‹!ιYes, I canι ¦⸿N…o n¹⁹!× Mama mia³⪫⪪“\`↖⮌3&℅⮌ü⎇Y,L¦⊞⊟η*"Ｄμ◧À⬤×(»q#⌕´⁸.₂Ｏ3K”¶”↶↥%q7*Ｊ↑º⌕+”Ｆ⪪, my only¶.¦¶⁺ SyntaxErrorι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZNRb9owEMff9ykOv5BIAaljq4b6NNG1YhodEn2pmj6Y5EgsOT7kOLB8enZ2Cg0UCUWOufvd3f9/yUppM5L6cFhaZVz0@puUiRZyG4nJzUQkMGszjbOS@KJWOYIj4NtnVWEdzWTtIhUn8C2O@cn3In6L775syEL0NYYOudQNh35g/pajZsSx99SsNebd/yqB2w7CDEZ0qWI@rGAjtVamSO09GdgjGNoDNRYK2YLcbqVFncCDFKesrjkBWnKVHz1aap9LhH2JqGtgmOO3dVNDQR/Jp/knZ7ODpcbkIE3OzJvbblxxxp472JMZOlgjaDLFdaaAFmUJkX/G4hITIldbrQJxRalJ@AfKDWuom6wEmRqoPZwTUxPyIZMuK9tLyisDlhpljcEYiII9qf0p3viQn3d6qZ1XbvL9el/lILVRamLwnZ0O3NeDKqQlWMjCqI3Kei0@Sq00Uq9OT1ryyzA9k1JcX6Kjse/W7Xkxwtb5FRTTKazJOY1s7YYnQys@MS/sEONxMuD8AO9XeKIEWmpYWVZp7Ev8wZrvB6GYr/aCdQJzH@AHVMfN7dV7EleHBeMXqD/u4PPmLmQloVLBhesmgEYHFfLqciWvv2EDoke1w9B4s2WnX/jAXwdUbc8K3CF/OmSMhIKjg0ZB6ndwwuEssG5TMz6m9T0QsGqNk/9@WUu2k@PucDiMdvo/) Link is to verbose version of code. Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
No no no no no no no! Mama mia Mama mia Mama mia let me go
Never gonna give, never gonna give (Give you up)
You are my SyntaxError, my only SyntaxError.
```

Next line:

```
No juggernaut can stop us, no 4000
```

Comment: This is my 4000th (undeleted) answer. I couldn't find any lyrics for `4000th` so I had to make do with a randomly searched lyric that included `4000` instead.

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

## Day 16. [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 487 bytes

```
Wẋ3j⁾, 
““ to “, ”m0j“¡⁶G»”
“Oh“u”ŒḄ⁺j”-¤ɼ⁶®⁾-u⁶“µçṃtẉṛ»”
“œɗ:eĖḤQO⁴ẹḂÐMẠ⁷¦ŒŒ%»“ la”ẋ8¤”
“ɗ%'Ƈạẉṗß¥TÄḍ^qĖ»⁶“ØQ¤[ṛŻċ¤»Ç”
“;Ȯṗạḥ!ƭ⁽5⁾Ỵ»⁶“¡Ḷqɓ®rʋʠ»Ç”
“¢wðÇ8ṗȤḃȯ}Ėdẇ³ʂƙḷĖẈß5ʋu⁴»”
“)ọa»“ “ (“)”j“⁸v°Ȧ¢eṠCÄ»$”
”A”aẋ31¤⁾h!”
“(“) “, (“) “, “ ”j“©V°»$“ÆƥṠ=_eiȯẸʂIḄɱƇ»”
99“×&ṛƲȯ8+c6»ɼ“¬!}Ẇ?ɠ'Ạ01nṄ»®”
“¡ñeḣCṀƝṃṘ¡mLṁĠ"61ṁḂ"Ẉ»;⁶¤ẋ3$ṖṖ“ṃƇṆḶẆ ßḲP!»”
“Ẉ¿Jl»“ịPẠ»⁺⁺“¡µƈ`ȯ»“ḅiṢ»⁺⁺Ṗ⁶99®⁾!
“©ƒḣȦdḋL»,Œl$j⁾, “£ZAɦŻ/ıṙċṫ»”
“€¦ẒtFḷœ»“f#İ⁽s»ɼ“¢ẈĊⱮĖu»®⁾.
“çḥƭ~l?JⱮŻṁ^ƊƊg|ʂ»⁶4ȷ”
“Na, na, ”⁾naWẋ4¤j”-¤;⁾, ¤⁺“¡ẠȥỤC»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVNtSxRRFP7er9g1zaK1lFTcJESEIrFUiIICa8ktldUwtQgynNVccxFihV0lF3fX2Q1J98V8uTO3DM68MLP/4swf2c6dWRfhztw7c85zXp7n3KlwJPKpVnuGavzOlCOdB3xXnKUdWr75dz7aAvRKT7dP0RGyjnT6ADj9ED7DE/RaoA8jgWzFkVTySbeBbP8hNyhSrLYFOgngifYTleV5VL@h8qMRwNi0U3fDehKZPDrsSMeoKsii2vdHqGYc6QwKRsJItAj3HV8kRCCqsQfkOtpOtbSaMVSzbtSUtgv5J9oKso2xWT1JIDeztjUK8gtKanA9DjJwLVaH91pFQgk4y/vNQ0f620UVIz@@gAJZTmftTSi@r8armUtQyH3Uylqsh/CWjGzZKi3qyXFUY/C7GjW3kZ1RT@qatttVjRMDx42GbyDfCHn9iOe6@EUmwa0jsQ9QtgqQC6OSGdBWgDd7qHQ/PSEhTwf1Lp1P@OvRXLgn0aWjF9yNCftPoezG2dFWzTzFvfcyPGmVUGXV6EPSzK6YMa@4YFA4pa4RU@aRVeq5@bobOAlJQQ78i6iu9tmZVpKlvWMGFaqN5K1zkdUqYWR7A6gsmWkSGZUtyE4PoSLpmabuDtpJ0yaiA3ivmAtZdNKMSpIW4QlBIiqrxDVl8Wm7yI5G/A3GBO7fYMTlDHl8hEoQ@qhiieRwYq69skqenX2dRCV3YRfxpdNg0J1Ev1vrvkmTumcVxpHFh4AHjESk2Zt5Yd173m8XDH5br6CyrcdR@dUow4keQAHVxPx9EtfYdNO9uaqXaWrmLnjKUa36ulMp6skFlyDp/JbA0uizvHn4JdI3SEaDEyNj5rq5/vZzNerOWqd1Vk/zOBTwzYTcG0fomZC4lJ0g1@9Vr1upmAGvd@LCyiOXB4DXav8B)

### Output

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
Never gonna give, never gonna give (Give you up)
You are my SyntaxError, my only SyntaxError.
No juggernaut can stop us, no 4000
Na, na, na-na-na-na, na-na-na-na, hey Jude
```

[Previous Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225583)

Next line: `I used to rule the world, chunks would load when I gave the word`

From CaptainSparklez's Fallen Kingdom (a Minecraft parody of Viva la Vida).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-sH53vXP2A

Answer (score 2):

## Day 0. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/Q8EAA)

Line for next day: `eor;n84pej8btp;8boeiuhtopwa8h5por58hob8h5p29h5]-925-j]wgip4o[35iwoueou9[-0etdojfuotpog;kcjliuxiokjdl`

Song:

---

```
  # full program
  # implicit output
```

Comment: Forgive me for not knowing what the song is, but what song is this? I'd like to listen to it.

Comment: @Lyxal `687*9/+84*+9/4+*-9+8849872345` by The Non-Existent Band. :P

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 39 bytes (boring)

```js
_=>'Baby shark doo doo doo-doo doo-doo'
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k7dKTGpUqE4I7EoWyElPx@GdZFo9f/J@XnF@Tmpejn56RppGpqa/wE)

## JavaScript, 53 bytes (more interesting)

```js
_=>'Baby shark'+' doo-doo'.repeat(3).replace('-',' ')
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##FcY7DoAgDADQq7AVorA44@BFTIXij1ACxsTTow4veQfeWF3Z86UTe2rBttmOMOHyiLphOaED4Zn1B0yhTHjJQf2L6EiChh4EqOY4VY5kIq8ySKXaCw)

The song so far is `Baby shark doo doo doo-doo doo-doo` and the next line is `I'm gonna get ya get ya get ya get ya` from Blondie's "One Way Or Another". Yes, 70s stuff.

Answer (score 2):

## Day 1, [PHP](https://php.net/), 34 bytes

```php
<?=$a=side," to $a, $a, $a to $a";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJdG2ODMlVUdJoSRfQSVRB4ohPCXr//8B)

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224578/90841)

Song so far:

```php
side to side, side, side to side
```

Next line: `Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh I'm falling` ([Twenty One Pilots "Ride"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw-0pbY9JeU))

Answer (score 2):

## Day 2, [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>103</s> 101 bytes

```python
a=' sword'
b=a+','+a
c='side'
d=c+' to '+c
print(d+f", {c}, {d}\ndo you like my{b},{a} my diamond"+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcaxDoQgDADQna9oXHqXsjnzJ7cUqpF4UqMYQwjfji4vby950TT2zg7hvPUQNN4xoUViExyeUSY04gIhZAWkYPYjpvwRmgcLNbQXab8kCkUv@Md1gq1U32zl9g4k8qZJBvLf3h8)

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224562/compose-a-song-line-by-line/224623#224623)

Song so far:

```python
side to side, side, side to side
do you like my sword, sword, sword my diamond sword, sword
```

Next line: `Wo-o-o-o-o-o-oah, wo-o-o-o-o-o-oah`  from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fTUj9mfnUk)

Comment: -2 with `d+f", {c}, {d}\ndo you like my{b},{a} my diamond"+b`.

Comment: [4 bytes longer but slightly more interesting](https://tio.run/##NYtBCoMwFESvMrskxVXdCb1JNz98i8EkX2ykBPHsaaK4mjePmSWnSWJfltXFpHXxFCwT6KW@jscOqrMVf7Jy5eFzWiTBTo/ncZeW78iCLBu8m0fYjN22RXsiZLCjIJGrvZwqRhtT/g)

Comment: [Even more interesting](https://tio.run/##NYhLCsIwEIav8u@SmK4UQQI9ibrIdCoGm0yoEQmlZ49VcPU9ci13SYdTnlueQypat8lHYg/fq2fgsYPqaNO3zLy5u/0uimDxu/36jy8viQVVXpjCYwRVLGT14HqydHbHq1kRKzj4KImh7NCMNqZ9AA). EDIT: Yes, I just realized there's a small typo. `by` should be `my`

Answer (score 2):

## Day 3. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 51 bytes. My score: \$8\frac{2}9\$

```
“We're€¸æÊs€„„Î
Youƒ€€€‰ï€ƒ€Ê€· I
A‚è©—'s€À I'm™Ð€‚
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOc8FT1otRHTWsO7Ti87HBXMZD1qGEeEB3u44rMLz02CSQAQQ0bDq8H0mChw10gLdsVPLkcHzXMOrzi0MpHDVPUQboPNyh4quc@all0eAJY06z//wE)

[**Previous answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224709/94066)

Line for next day: `You wouldn't get this from any other guy`

Song:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
```

---

```
“...  # trimmed program
“...  # push "We're no strangers to love\nYou know the rules and so do I\nA full commitment's what I'm thinking of"
      # (implicit) end compressed string
      # implicit output
```

Comment: excellent. the roll continues.

Answer (score 2):

## Day 3,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 160 bytes

```
A{B{\s\i\d\e}BZ{\ }Z\t\oZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
D{E{F{\O\h}F\-\u}E\-}DDFZDDEZ\I\'\mZ\f\a\l\l\i\n\g\
\D\o\nZ\w\eZ\n\o\wZ\o\u\rZ\g\a\yZ\a\p\p\a\r\e\lC\F\aG{Z\l\a}GGGGGGGG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVNj9owEL3nV4xyKbQbRJC60qKlEp@rnno3w8ElhlgNTuQYKIry2@kEAiRASD@2EymS7fHMvJc3k2hn/FB19pEOl9ADbdv2vp8MEoxRoociHbAEIWVoMGSDdJjgE0v7w8Gwj9YoGSeTBL@hn07QwXU6RicdjSZsNBoz/IofcMVwgRwDeiQqXKKFIwxRMdyiYLQT4pbRa42a0SnHHaNXRA9HjQKDIU6QvyWMAvD07WR7qtKy5CoKtYF4F1tkK7Gi@qe2PYOP0Hm2rK0vAwGBUI0MWxO@QLtrAZlcQKi9w@60PaODHjx/Bq688vZrD17yG5ltKHrbOi8lLTvnlUcr97xStMoKPPsuSmW4l6D56SGnO4Me3Uvs8nFmRyjeBcK1UQwJr5cs971OtSn4dEwpZ1al46kseSwL0a4OeiJEUmD3sddvF1pV8CNfEcSiPmKkpTJgj7UO9ROs1YqbuS/VEr5rPv8hTAxSgfHFIaXmq5ZdG5I02BI/pWk0rerarhhN6ggtyFSCA@59qZ6OruRaZZlSvdrP9DdEntnbShopawMc4iggD6GJUE/OuQn1f@IyreHyiNqpQP0Y7TvKpQZadQvRcJuWhpNDOphlnTHtOu5tU2xK86hMmVtN2TtAvQOREm@ylFfqzP84FdDyhne7F3C3nykPcVRC7nkB2r4zuR6P4qz42Hgk3tZWSyMaOWHNhzUUOeMK6HZE6pcqNno9NzJUhY6Y@5yozFrChLnnFYl3CCzC7FTBLI6Tf2vMqwpuMqWVmf5IMTdpiswWIWca2P8C)

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224764/100664)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la la
```

Next line: `The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round`

Comment: Sorry, I had one to many `la`s in my answer. I hope that's not a problem...

Comment: @Neil It's not, I can take off a G from the end.

Answer (score 2):

## Day 4,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), <s>243</s> 235 bytes

```
\WA{\e}B{\'}ABG{\r}GAC{\ }CH{\o}N{\n}NHCJ{\s}JT{\t}TGZ{\a}ZN\gAGJCTHCX{\l}XH\vA\
D{\YHU{\u}U}DC\kNH\wF{T\h}CFACGUXAJCZN\dCJHC\dHC\I\
\AC\fUXXC\cHM{\m}MM\iTMANTBJC\w\hZTC\IBMCF\iN\k\iN\gCH\f\
DC\wHUX\dNBTC\gATCF\iJC\fGHMCZN\yCHFAGC\gU\y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXbjtpADH3PV1h56W5bVgSpK3W1VArTQopEnoJKF/OQkkBGCwmaDFA0mm@nzhIgXAK9bEcCybHH9jk5dmYrGSVxbT0TyRjqIEzTXOM3W2GoGwrfaLvRUih0y2YKQTNHYaJdhbF2HdZWmOq2p1Bqr/Wk0NdPLo7tVpt5DuspnOiegwsbjc8KvztdhXPd1Z8ZPrsOLpvKw0izps1a3Z7dZnQ1YG2HYUC/r2igzXDU7fUYDp2OwqnudJB7Hdv1Gm2GS4yePIprdFgTuYvP2d@YOTiiauR2uj0M3AaFjG0vC6E7o5bTycqsmNO0W@Tp4mpNeA2DT2eJkJCuUoPONJwSE33THMBbqN0bxjLikxAmYXyTsXQLn6D6YAAdPoJEBC9P@9UBOepw/wH8ODh8/FiHj/mN7Cwoe9XYmZzM2s4KyLJ2VkxW1uAudnTQhrVPmntfaloDqNM9ZR66s7OBEuwhHB/KweFxX@V81La3GN5tSvKBURq4bYtv2kI0y5NuCeGU2Loc9duNljV8KTacpOH1jDPBYwnmFyES8R7m8dSXw4jHY/gh/OFzKFPgMcgofCkp/OmdeTUlafAu/Mnlza1R3tsRo@oaoQWZcqiAdV6qW9eRXMtOptTg6mv6GyJ37C05Lae5BB/S2YQiQkGEBnzoy0T8Jy71FS43qCslqC@jfUW5XIFWPkK03PoHy6lCOhhkk9F/qFinQ7E42EeHlFnllL0C1DMQqfAiK3mkzvzbVQItH3jrYQ/u9DXlKTZKyCP3QKtnNtflVZw1n8qAxHu3FFyGNzlhtxd7KHLmx0C3Z6R@HqdSzIeSJ3FhIoaRT1RmIyGTPPKIxDMEFmHWymAW18m/DeZRByeVdGmlP1LMSZkis0XImQbWvwA)

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224814/100664)

Song so far:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
```

Next line: `I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling`

Answer (score 2):

## Day 4. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 72 bytes. My score: \$9.125\$

```
“We're€¸æÊs€„„Î
Youƒ€€€‰ï€ƒ€Ê€· I
A‚è©—'s€À I'm™Ð€‚
You€Þn't€Õ€Œ€š€Æ€¶ïí
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOc8FT1otRHTWsO7Ti87HBXMZD1qGEeEB3u44rMLz02CSQAQQ0bDq8H0mChw10gLdsVPLkcHzXMOrzi0MpHDVPUQboPNyh4quc@all0eAJY0yyQMSDxeXnqJSB6KpA4CjLj6EIQtw1k0LbD6w@v/f8fAA)

[**Previous answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224847/94066)

Line for next day: `I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling`

Song:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
```

---

```
“...  # trimmed program
“...  # push "We're no strangers to love\nYou know the rules and so do I\nA full commitment's what I'm thinking of\nYou wouldn't get this from any other guy"
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Day 4, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 119 bytes

```
⟦⪫Ｅ313…side to ×Ｉι⁴, ⟧Ｆ²⁺…Oh-u-⊗⁺ι⁶ “P➙⭆BＸ5↶÷ρ⦄⟧⁸A>ιZ›➙πα⊗σ*7¹´$⁹“ＢzＩ⊞³⌈”× la⁸“[¶²/;pv﹪ＨD⦃»ⅉδE4pＰf·⁹E”⪫Ｅ³… round and¹⁶,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Ba8MwDIXv@xXCl9mQHNqMMtgxZbBBWQ@9rTuoiRsbVCvY8UJ/faZhaLeLQE96n/Q6h7FjpGXZRx8m/fnOPugdjlo1q0ZV0F47sq1jEZLvLUwMoh78xSbdYpq0NxU8GSNVdGW@zMvDmSPotYGC3FOW1Tvmw9W5lt0t5xPZvsx9BZsCEYYgilW9PV7gjEQ@DMe45QCzhcAzcI4w4BVwHDFaquAV1c1VnlNAKFee/9CO8eAszM5aSiCwSbpTTjDw3XzL3/zLDpFz6AFDL8zVpsT9/XRZlvqbfgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
```

Next line:

```
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Day 6,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 313 bytes

```
\WA{\e}A\'G{\r}GAC{\ }CH{\o}N{\n}NHCJ{\s}JT{\t}TGZ{\a}ZN\gAGJCTHCX{\l}XH\vA\
\YV{HU{\u}UC}V\kNH\wF{T\h}CFACGUXAJCZN\dCJHC\dHC\I\
\AC\fUXXC\cHM{\m}MM\iTMANT\'JC\w\hZTC\I\'MCF\iN\kY{\iN\g}YCH\f\
\YV\wHUX\dN\'TC\gATCF\iJC\fGHMCZN\yCHFAGC\gU\y\
\IC\jUJTC\wZNNZCTAXXC\yV\hH\wC\I\'MC\fAAXY\
\GHTTZCMZ\kAC\yVUN\dAGJTZN\d
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225010/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXbjtowEH3PV1h5YbctK4LUlbpaKllWSRaJPCVbLsNDSgJxgQQlARZZ/nY6hnAn0MvWEkKOj2fmnJyZTJdZGEfV1TSJh6RGEl3XV/CdCggkhZIpIJEmZQKIZJaAWNoCImlbrCEglQ1HQCYdsyPAkx0bhtRsMMdiLQFj2bJgTkGD9quwXAEz6TL5CiPbgkVdOBBKVqfMdFu0wfCqzxoWAx9/L3iHMhi4rRaDvtUUMJHNJnCnSW0HSg0GCwg7jgKWmqwO3IZRW6i/oWwzCwbrnLCw3Bb4NpQQOaSOAuLVgWk1Vbols@rUxBMXloh/YfDTbSBy0bHtDnOoyr18hRCLzRPBgNJWG7Gm5Tgd1uzAiCqMi7UjbUdxWKF6msYn0zjJSLpMNVyTYIK6dnW9Rz6Q6qOmLUI@Dsg4iO6U5vfkK6k8aQQXH5A48ddPu5UeHtTI42fiRf7x4@ca@ZLfUGuO0SvabstxW93tfNwZu12EO1XgDjs4KsPYB81P1zmNHqnhPaEfH6u1oeLvKZwujMHJ8z7LZdS2toh83KTkPa0QuC2Lb8oC0IuDbgXhGNi4jvrtQosKvoYNxmlwO@I04VFG9G9JEiefyCyaeFk/5NGQ/Ei8/ijIUsIjkoXBOmXiTR70myHRgw/BG8/u7rXi2k4UFbcEPbApJ2ViXLbq9ujErkVLOdW/@Zr@RsideguOo26WEY@k0zEiggQF9Xnfy@LkP2kpb2i5YV0uYH2d7Tva5Qa14hbC4dY9Gk5l9EFPdUb3qWycN8X8aB4dS2YUS/YOVC9QxMRzlfLEnfmXsIBa3vDG057c@WvKQ2yckCP3RCsXJtf1UayKTzMfzfuwSHgW3OWC3V@t4VAzLyJ4e4ru51GaJbN@xuPooCP6oYdSqpbI4hx5IuIFAQ9pVotoHo6Tf2vMkwrOMsnCTH/kmLM0h8oeUlYeWP0C)

Song so far:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
```

Next line: `Never gonna give you up`

Answer (score 2):

### Golfed version of [@StackMeter's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225357/101522), 389 bytes

The link for this doesn’t fit in a comment, and with all the backticks, the code doesn’t format properly either, so here is the golfed code as an answer instead. It uses dictionary compression, with a hint of string compression, and some register shenanigans to compress the code from a readable 656 bytes to 389 bytes of pure gibberish.

```
`⟇ɽ to ⟇ɽ`£¥`, ⟇ɽ, `¥¶
`Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh`:ð$`-u I'm ẋµ
›⌐ we λṠ λġ ∨¬ ʀḊ, Fa`` la`8*`
λƛ ḃ† on λλ ʀė go`` €ḭ λ¬ €ḭ,`DṪ`
It ¨„'t be ¬□`` ›β (›β),`DṪ`
So`ð«»|F→«+£¥\,¥`, it's ƛȯ a`¥` †ṁ
ƛṡ ``›¢'t be ¬□`£¥‛ (¥`)
A`\a31*`h!
(`«ƛġ(Ǒ§«ǐ£¥‛) ¥`, (`¥‛) ¥‛, ¥ð«»∴r#⁽⌈ḢßÞẋ«ǐ‛-o4*¶
`99 ∑∪ of β□`£¥` on λλ ½ø, `¥¶
`No, λ• λ‹'t.`£¥` ∨ṗ, I λ‹. `+:¥` ∨ṗ, I λ‹`:\,$`!
If I ``÷¯, `D`I λ‹`` ↑¾,`DṪ` 99 ∑∪ of β□!
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%AA&code=%60%E2%9F%87%C9%BD%20to%20%E2%9F%87%C9%BD%60%C2%A3%C2%A5%60%2C%20%E2%9F%87%C9%BD%2C%20%60%C2%A5%C2%B6%0A%60Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh%60%3A%C3%B0%24%60-u%20I%27m%20%E1%BA%8B%C2%B5%0A%E2%80%BA%E2%8C%90%20we%20%CE%BB%E1%B9%A0%20%CE%BB%C4%A1%20%E2%88%A8%C2%AC%20%CA%80%E1%B8%8A%2C%20Fa%60%60%20la%608*%60%0A%CE%BB%C6%9B%20%E1%B8%83%E2%80%A0%20on%20%CE%BB%CE%BB%20%CA%80%C4%97%20go%60%60%20%E2%82%AC%E1%B8%AD%20%CE%BB%C2%AC%20%E2%82%AC%E1%B8%AD%2C%60D%E1%B9%AA%60%0AIt%20%C2%A8%E2%80%9E%27t%20be%20%C2%AC%E2%96%A1%60%60%20%E2%80%BA%CE%B2%20%28%E2%80%BA%CE%B2%29%2C%60D%E1%B9%AA%60%0ASo%60%C3%B0%C2%AB%C2%BB%7CF%E2%86%92%C2%AB%2B%C2%A3%C2%A5%5C%2C%C2%A5%60%2C%20it%27s%20%C6%9B%C8%AF%20a%60%C2%A5%60%20%E2%80%A0%E1%B9%81%0A%C6%9B%E1%B9%A1%20%60%60%E2%80%BA%C2%A2%27t%20be%20%C2%AC%E2%96%A1%60%C2%A3%C2%A5%E2%80%9B%20%28%C2%A5%60%29%0AA%60%5Ca31*%60h!%0A%28%60%C2%AB%C6%9B%C4%A1%28%C7%91%C2%A7%C2%AB%C7%90%C2%A3%C2%A5%E2%80%9B%29%20%C2%A5%60%2C%20%28%60%C2%A5%E2%80%9B%29%20%C2%A5%E2%80%9B%2C%20%C2%A5%C3%B0%C2%AB%C2%BB%E2%88%B4r%23%E2%81%BD%E2%8C%88%E1%B8%A2%C3%9F%C3%9E%E1%BA%8B%C2%AB%C7%90%E2%80%9B-o4*%C2%B6%0A%6099%20%E2%88%91%E2%88%AA%20of%20%CE%B2%E2%96%A1%60%C2%A3%C2%A5%60%20on%20%CE%BB%CE%BB%20%C2%BD%C3%B8%2C%20%60%C2%A5%C2%B6%0A%60No%2C%20%CE%BB%E2%80%A2%20%CE%BB%E2%80%B9%27t.%60%C2%A3%C2%A5%60%20%E2%88%A8%E1%B9%97%2C%20I%20%CE%BB%E2%80%B9.%20%60%2B%3A%C2%A5%60%20%E2%88%A8%E1%B9%97%2C%20I%20%CE%BB%E2%80%B9%60%3A%5C%2C%24%60!%0AIf%20I%20%60%60%C3%B7%C2%AF%2C%20%60D%60I%20%CE%BB%E2%80%B9%60%60%20%E2%86%91%C2%BE%2C%60D%E1%B9%AA%60%2099%20%E2%88%91%E2%88%AA%20of%20%CE%B2%E2%96%A1!&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## Day 14

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 725 bytes

```python
print("""side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules, and so do I""")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJNa8MwDL37V7z20gTcUtguPQ5GRw77gA1Gj26rxKGeVWxnIb8@s0u6tazbYI4jvSeBJEvad0Gzver7vattyMbjsa@3hMBIWp7Io0086mkzHQROybRBMXlDqYypbSVu2aIlWG7BjUOlOqj9XjkyEksFc/mKF01oNZHxiAFCZOvGo2I4buwWKv4HJP80iCKgZTsJWBMM2wodKY0syVz@SMQzY6PCRnfyU9dh4uGbjYYabPAxoHgypDxhe5YlO6O5uFG/Hz0S2Z0ytSHOMQCJC6YBYFlXyjHuVWXrst7wdPjEYoE1h2Ao9q6MBZA79rCNQ5H47hcPMW7HTXxVrHmGFXmJIrEZ/uOSJ3gkijKi4GIDv8TBhW1ct508UxeqG4lXmri0Q/DBKVuR82kPDb@TWMX8u7Rd6X2uMSlvmr3nOA8UcZXzvu@v5/MP)

The return of a legendary meme.

Next line: `[ignore everything before this line]`, to distingiush the rickroll from the non-rickroll.

Comment: I appreciate you continuing the song, but I'm sure this could be compressed at least a little.

Comment: It might be, but I wouldn't know how

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/206634/revisions Here are some examples of python 3 compression tricks

Answer (score 2):

## Day 16

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 786 bytes

```python
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = "side to side", "Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh ", "la ", " round and round", " yeah (yeah)", "catchy", "Galileo (Galileo), ", "99 bottles of beer ", "No you can't. ", "Yes, I can. "  
print(a+", side,"+a+"\n"+b+b+"I'm falling\nDon we now our gay apparel, Fa "+c*8+"\nThe wheels on the bus go"+d+","+d+","+d+"\nIt won't be long"+e+","+e+","+e+"So"+f+","+f+", it's such a"+f+" song\n" +"Please don't be long (don't be long)\nAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!\n"+g*2+"Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o\n"+h+"on the wall, "+h +"\n"+i+(j+i)*2+"Yes, I can, Yes, I can!\nIf I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!\n[ignore everything before this line]\nWe\'re no strangers to love\nYou know the rules and so do I\nA full commitment's what I'm thinking of")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJLj9MwEL7zKz58abt2OcCFPXBAQot64CGBhFZkD24yib117cp2NsqvLzOh2oeQSJTxzDfxvL45zdWl@O58tgZ7g9agMyCD3mAwcAbe4B4foIrvCDVBTmWgvrntuL0ICBDsciCnMXaw/C3ags1kHdYiN2K3trZuFu2zDT5QwvqibMwS5Poa@1RroILUY0@UF/hrwpxGtDau6psFuaVisBOEbeDVKftY11azTwo1SrPeRKX3/Krd6ojehuDj0MRPKWIixDQhjRmDnWFPJ5spGNxwL7q9ei93fzrC5IgC1xJR2dqPBUNSuuM0z2QTdxVT4tq4YoQUB6VpcT7KH3yrXwyR8HVVUMbWwS4ISpLKFLT6HsgWQvc8HNYvzE0TP9r/P@619D5cvdWPk77xg80JX@wQfe/btL288qPT6tLixFPi8WqHv@Pzen2v/UYCPY3c4EnnRLue1Zpn80wsPnTMysG8OPAvxRzitx9iygR6oMyLyTyxpxeEjQImju6a@IuaVRbmUGq2caBcZDNDeqAm3vKCHIRUaSOPEl92sSSeJXY8MvRjCGjT8ejrkaJQMDlbIcshKQ@SNfVqcz7/AQ)

[Previous answer:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225584/100887)

Compression is not worth it. Like, I think this is longer than the raw text.

Line for Day 17: `You wouldn't get this from any other guy`

Comment: Nice! You can use h in `if I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink, 99 bottles of beer`

Comment: Also, the raw text is 790, + `print('''` and `''')` is 803.

Comment: 766 bytes by removing spaces between `a, b` `c, d` etc and `"side to side", "Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh"` etc.

Comment: http://tio.run/##VVLLihsxELzrK8pzGT/kQOJL9pDDQtjgQx6QQFiWHGRPz4zWstpImh2MmG93Wo6XJYhuVRV6tKp1Oqee/eZyMXqnG0261Z3utdXP@vCpirYhJEaZK11979fD@paEIvDgGxiJKyrSmUyPecmLQvcm7fuzoC/GWUeM@Q0sdKVR3d1hxyk5iuAWO6IgS7@xxpkH2evr9A6iPFLU2BbhSll0WQzHvqvUKVif5mbVVpUcWSrV2Uwq7yZIrAds6yNa45z1nfrMHiPB8wgeAjpzhjmdTCCn8WCQa2dQLz9O6ldPGHsiJ5V5JGG7IaLj3Ez6FmqbMObDlEnov1A/ObeCJGBTHRGHfQ8jHFGKVT8cmUhoZBfmJS/Ufa5Nvdy8n/qZyt2qm16derCdCYyvpvO2tXte34bK/fRa0yjP0hBBZbuaP6/sYvlhenNL4w3P1LYVlOsUzlreuJmuMhqx76D/m8qBM/VkO8@BQC8U5JOIe@J5WxQhEWIn/VG/qQ7FTsQUjO8oxPJdHL@QepQWHorRpdAwlB6XnxIZDWOr7tEOzmHPx6NNR/LFrbE36dquct2h3Milq4vL5S8

Comment: The above is 668 bytes and can just fit in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 2. [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 39 bytes

```
“q5ėvYṘṢtQṠ¦kvɓ%Ʋ^¶&_ẇƥ,7[ỴwḞƬ(aɱp⁵GṣĠ»
```

[Try it online!](https://bit.ly/3gOJh1Q)

[Alternatively, here's a rickroll](https://tio.run/##AUwAs/9qZWxsef//4oCccTXEl3ZZ4bmY4bmidFHhuaDCpmt2yZMlxrJewrYmX@G6h8alLDdb4bu0d@G4nsasKGHJsXDigbVH4bmjxKDCu///)

[Previous Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224638/78850)

Line for tomorrow: `A full commitment's what I'm thinking of`

Currently we have:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
```

Comment: Even Bitly knows rickrolls are harmful.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 2,  Functional Deadfish~, 328 bytes

```
{iiiiii}iiiiiic{iii}icic{ii}iiic{{d}i}ic{iiiii}ic{ii}ic{d}iiic{ii}dddc{d}iiiciiiif{{d}ii}ic{{i}ddd}ddc{i}iccfCCCif{{d}iii}iiic{{i}dddd}dddddc{i}iccifCdCiC{{d}}ddc{ii}iif{{i}d}dc{d}ciiiiiic{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddd}iiiiic{d}dddcfC{{d}iii}ic{{i}dd}ddciciiiiic{{d}ii}ddddc{iiii}iic{iiii}dddc{ddd}ddddddc{iii}ciiiiic{d}iiic{dddddd}ic{d}ddcC
```

[Try it online!](https://deadfish.surge.sh/func#CzUOx2Qvt7tN//n/5v8zm/Pzazmb/8zfmaz834qaz8/4Ws+Zt4rFN5kgIjhaz+fm3irFVN5k4CjjayKb88LeMTWH/82s+ebeKz/zWKkBtZ/M28WKc/+bWfFU3/nm/8VNViqpv8P/ms/NVVmaxSI=)

Decided to broaden my horizons.

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224562/compose-a-song-line-by-line/224617#224617)

Song so far:

```
Baby Shark doo doo doo-doo doo-doo
you're not JoKing, you're
```

Next line: `The chicken-woman-duck thing waiting in the bushes for us`, from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RySHDUU2juM&list=PLDWOaLX7rvz2c9FovuAIFcocP--3o2oI7&index=5)

Comment: the fact that i know exactly what song the next line is without having to click on the link is kinda odd.

Comment: @Lyxal I thought I was the only one here who liked Bad Lip Reading.

Comment: Obviously not :p

Answer (score 1):

## Day 2, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 48 bytes

```
⟦⪫Ｅ313…side to ×Ｉι⁴, ⟧Ｆ²⁺…Oh-u-⊗⁺ι⁶ ¦I'm falling
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxC8IwEIV3f8WRxRy0g1ZcOraLgtjBTRxim5qDayNtIvjr40EGlzd8772vd2bpveGUuoXmoO9nT7O@mLdW1a5SBTTfnm3jvICVBgvBg9AbTXbVjVmDJizggCgpXOED683oF9B7hKzsOMr0r7m6MpaybX18sh1yTwUcs0QcoshXddpOMBpmml8K65RS@eEf) Link is to verbose version of code. Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side       
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
```

Next line:

```
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
```

Comment: I think you might have one extra `la` in there.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 3, Javascript (ES6), 435/472/594/410 bytes

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224707)

### Boringly print the string, 436 bytes

```js
x=>(f=`I'm only human after all
`)+f+`ᤴ헚`
```

### Compress to base33 and get the values, 510 bytes

```js
_=>x=>(f=`I'm only human after all
`)+f+`gjtomnvbcug2ioporpuupdio6qpq8calmmgtgukhuj1k2ofmt5ogo4jk05uhipg8mdmm9k11t6j0g6jcg8qmgi6folsrgwlr3sj9j406bvfd8rsu9a53q82iu12di2jifkgdbk5shmp46cpnbbs9nmn1c19ecfuu8lrs3a5l4ci3l5p4cvtpdowib38kgjgliwobrdt7clbvgv8q34nj7r4nhtrqf24bklgbatgougj27citmvdndt5gm5u7i053cls3rqlpu3qkjt5tjbd9fvq47duahgwf6f8571d2ssmoln2vsm3t1pa32156liqhm8sjonq8b0r5tudr1u249a9fcjklt0uq2gdlj41tqbfr6bphc3nekpipbvv46cra637k1h8w6hm22h95`.match(/..../g).map(x=>String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(x,33))).join``
```

### Go a step further and reverse base64 the whole thing: 595/411 bytes

```js
_=>(f=`I'm only human after all
`)+f+btoa`‚;hš{Ûrè6ŠŠh®›®¥Ø¨êªjñÆ¥šh-‚é!º=dÚ‡æ·š £ˆäÓ›¡Š˜<™Ù¦öMu·¨ôƒ¨ÜƒÊ¦‚.Ÿ¢[+ƒ    kÞÈý:n÷Ýò».õ®w«Í¢»]‹hâ~HnNl†jxéÊgm»=žiõs_^qû®òZìÝ®eáÈ·—šxrûivŒ"o$‚8%‹
­Û{rVï‚ÿ*ß‰ãî¾'†Úên’XjØ(ºöíÈ­š÷gvÞ\`››»‹Nwr[7®©i»z¤ŽÞm·}~ú¸íÛš†éÿ9ïWv²É¨–}¯²míÖ–·Û^z–*¡›Ë#¢z¼oJù¶çkÖí¸õ¯_r9%·KªÚem©·ëéºasyÞ’˜©nûøéÊÚë~äÖ0ê¶Úy`.match(/..../g).map(x=>String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(x,33))).join``
```

Contains some unprintables so will be a little mangled. The reason I say  594/410 is because while it is 594 bytes, most golfing languages have a 256-byte SBCS, and all the "2-byte" characters are between charcodes 128 and 256. Counting all of these as 1-byte characters results in 410.

Hexdump:

```js
00000000: 5f3d 3e28 663d 2249 276d 206f 6e6c 7920  _=>(f="I'm only 
00000010: 6875 6d61 6e20 6166 7465 7220 616c 6c22  human after all"
00000020: 292b 662b 6274 6f61 60c2 823b 68c2 9a7b  )+f+btoa`..;h..{
00000030: c39b 72c3 a836 c28a c28a 68c2 aec2 9bc2  ..r..6....h.....
00000040: aec2 a5c3 98c2 a8c3 aac2 aa6a c3b1 c386  ...........j....
00000050: c2a5 c29a 682d c282 c3a9 21c2 ba3d 64c3  ....h-....!..=d.
00000060: 9ac2 87c3 a6c2 b7c2 9a20 c2a3 c288 c3a4  ......... ......
00000070: c393 c29b c2a1 c28a c298 3cc2 99c3 99c2  ..........<.....
00000080: a6c3 b64d 75c2 b7c2 a8c3 b4c2 83c2 a8c3  ...Mu...........
00000090: 9cc2 83c3 8ac2 a6c2 822e c29f c2a2 5b2b  ..............[+
000000a0: c283 096b c39e c388 c3bd c28f c28d 3a6e  ...k..........:n
000000b0: c3b7 c39d c3b2 c2bb 2ec3 b5c2 ae77 c2ab  .............w..
000000c0: c38d c2a2 c2bb 5dc2 9dc2 8b68 c3a2 7e48  ......]....h..~H
000000d0: 1d6e 4e6c c286 6a78 c3a9 c38a 676d c2bb  .nNl..jx....gm..
000000e0: 3dc2 9e69 c3b5 735f 5e71 c3bb c2ae c3b2  =..i..s_^q......
000000f0: 5ac3 acc3 9dc2 ae65 c3a1 c388 c2b7 c297  Z......e........
00000100: c29a 7872 c3bb 6976 c28c 226f 7f24 c282  ..xr..iv.."o.$..
00000110: 3825 c28b 0a1b c2ad c39b 7b72 56c3 afc2  8%........{rV...
00000120: 82c3 bf2a c39f c289 c3a3 c3ae c2be 27c2  ...*..........'.
00000130: 86c3 9ac3 aa7f 6e1b c292 581b 6ac3 9828  ......n...X.j..(
00000140: c2ba 08c3 b6c3 adc3 88c2 adc2 9ac3 b767  ...............g
00000150: 76c3 9e5c 60c2 9bc2 9bc2 bbc2 8b4e 7772  v..\`........Nwr
00000160: 5b37 c2ae c2a9 69c2 bb7a c2a4 c28e c39e  [7....i..z......
00000170: 6dc2 8dc2 b77d 7ec3 bac2 b8c3 adc3 9bc2  m....}~.........
00000180: 9ac2 860c 1fc3 a9c3 bf39 c3af 5776 c2b2  .........9..Wv..
00000190: c389 c2a8 c296 7dc2 afc2 b26d c3ad c396  ......}....m....
000001a0: c296 c2b7 c39b 5e7a c296 2ac2 a1c2 9bc3  ......^z..*.....
000001b0: 8b23 c2a2 7ac2 bc6f 4ac3 b9c2 b6c3 a76b  .#..z..oJ......k
000001c0: c396 c3ad c2b8 c3b5 c2af 5f72 3925 c2b7  .........._r9%..
000001d0: 4bc2 aac3 9a07 65c2 8fc2 8d6d c2a9 c2b7  K.....e....m....
000001e0: c3ab c3a9 c2ba 6173 79c3 9ec2 92c2 98c2  ......asy.......
000001f0: a96e c3bb c3b8 c3a9 c38a c39a c3ab 7ec3  .n............~.
00000200: a4c3 961f 30c3 aa19 c2b6 c39a 1f79 602e  ....0........y`.
00000210: 6d61 7463 6828 2f2e 2e2e 2e2f 6729 2e6d  match(/..../g).m
00000220: 6170 2878 3d3e 5374 7269 6e67 2e66 726f  ap(x=>String.fro
00000230: 6d43 6f64 6550 6f69 6e74 2870 6172 7365  mCodePoint(parse
00000240: 496e 7428 782c 3333 2929 292e 6a6f 696e  Int(x,33))).join
00000250: 6060                                     ``
```

To @Makonede: Never mind what I said about the singing lessons. You are beyond saving.

Song so far:

```js
I'm only human after all
I'm only human after all
ᤴ헚
```

Next line: `Galileo Galileo Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o` from [Bohemian Rhapsody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ9rUzIMcZQ)

Comment: Your answer is invalid as you did not specify a next line.

Comment: What @Makonede is right - you have to put a next line in your answer.

Comment: @Makonede Oops, will do

Comment: Your answer is still invalid, as there are no newlines in the output.

Comment: @Makonede My bad.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 3

## Python 3, 111 bytes

```python
print("""We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of""")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc3BDYMwDAXQO1N85ZJW6q0TcGQC1GNUDIlIbBQ7RUyfMsDTOy6Lwu/ej5rYHs65mXwlsECtBt6oKkyQ5UfDRxp2lhMWCbVl0hcCL1DBIpiGEWvLGV8pJVkhNq84YzBMvtwm8Z54g6z38uz9Dw)

[Continued from here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224709/100887)

Next line: `You wouldn't get this from any other guy`

Edit 1: (since the comma wasn't there, we get to experience 1-ception)

Comment: There is no comma in the answer you continued from.

Comment: The comma is gone now, and in its place 1-ception

Comment: Nice. If you end up golfing this, you can start a new joke: crossed out 111 is 444

Answer (score 1):

## Day 5,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 283 bytes

```
L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}A{B{\s\i\dP}BZ{\ }Z\tLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
D{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}DDFZDDEZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\u\rZ\gN\yZN\p\pN\rPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPO\sZLQZ\tMPZ\b\u\sZ\gLZH{\rL\uQ\d}I{HZNQ\dZH}ICICI\
\I\tZ\wLQ\'\tZ\bPZOLQ\gZJ{\yPN\h}K{JZ\(J\)}KCKCK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXbjtpADH3PV1h56W5bVgSpK3W1VArTQopEnoJKF/OQkkBGCwmaDFA0mm@nzhIgXAK9bEcCybHH9jk5dmYrGSVxbT0TyRjqIEzTXOM3W2GoGwrfaLvRUih0y2YKQTNHYaJdhbF2HdZWmOq2p1Bqr/Wk0NdPLo7tVpt5DuspnOiegwsbjc8KvztdhXPd1Z8ZPrsOLpvKw0izps1a3Z7dZnQ1YG2HYUC/r2igzXDU7fUYDp2OwqnudJB7Hdv1Gm2GS4yePIprdFgTuYvP2d@YOTiiauR2uj0M3AaFjG0vC6E7o5bTycqsmNO0W@Tp4mpNeA2DT2eJkJCuUoPONJwSE33THMBbqN0bxjLikxAmYXyTsXQLn6D6YAAdPoJEBC9P@9UBOepw/wH8ODh8/FiHj/mN7Cwoe9XYmZzM2s4KyLJ2VkxW1uAudnTQhrVPmntfaloDqNM9ZR66s7OBEuwhHB/KweFxX@V81La3GN5tSvKBURq4bYtv2kI0y5NuCeGU2Loc9duNljV8KTacpOH1jDPBYwnmFyES8R7m8dSXw4jHY/gh/OFzKFPgMcgofCkp/OmdeTUlafAu/Mnlza1R3tsRo@oaoQWZcqiAdV6qW9eRXMtOptTg6mv6GyJ37C05Lae5BB/S2YQiQkGEBnzoy0T8Jy71FS43qCslqC@jfUW5XIFWPkK03PoHy6lCOhhkk9F/qFinQ7E42EeHlFnllL0C1DMQqfAiK3mkzvzbVQItH3jrYQ/u9DXlKTZKyCP3QKtnNtflVZw1n8qAxHu3FFyGNzlhtxd7KHLmx0C3Z6R@HqdSzIeSJ3FhIoaRT1RmIyGTPPKIxDMEFmHWymAW18m/DeZRByeVdGmlP1LMSZkis0XImQbWvwA)

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224919/100664)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side                                          
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling                                   
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la                    
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
```

Next line: `So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song` from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jY8OR1haO88)

Answer (score 1):

## Day 5,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 284 bytes

```
\WA{\e}A\'G{\r}GAC{\ }CH{\o}N{\n}NHCJ{\s}JT{\t}TGZ{\a}ZN\gAGJCTHCX{\l}XH\vA\
D{\YHU{\u}U}DC\kNH\wF{T\h}CFACGUXAJCZN\dCJHC\dHC\I\
\AC\fUXXC\cHM{\m}MM\iTMANT\'JC\w\hZTC\I\'MCF\iN\kY{\iN\g}YCH\f\
DC\wHUX\dN\'TC\gATCF\iJC\fGHMCZN\yCHFAGC\gU\y\
\IC\jUJTC\wZNNZCTAXXC\yHUC\hH\wC\I\'MC\fAAXY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXbjtowEH3PV1h5YbctK4LUlbpaKkXeQhaJPCUql@EhJYG4CwlyDCyy/O10vIQ7gV62lhByfDxnzsnMZLoUcZpUV1OejkiNcNM0V/DdlhApG0oNCVw1bCqBKOpISJUrIVGuQ5sSMtX0JAjlNboSAtV1YWQ3mtRzaFvCWLUdmNtgPEnoOL6EmfLVE4UX14FFXXoQK1q3acNv202KV0PadCiE@HsGA2wKQ7/dpjBwWhImqtUC5rVs14NSk8IC4q6ngaUWrQNz4aUj9d9IdagDQ@REjOO3IXShhMCR7Wkc3hw2nJZmW1KnbjfwxIcl0j1T@Ok3Ebnoum6XeramXjo@hRizzZlgaNvtzgoNMgw2maZckGyZGbgm0QSt65lmn3wg1XvDWMRsHJFxlNxoW2/JV1J5MAguNiQpD9@e9ip9PKiR@88kSMLDx4818iW/odcco1eM7ZbhtrrdhbiztrsEdzrBLXZ4kIa1C5qfvnFafVLDe9I8PNZrLSXcSTheGIORxx3LedQmt4R8XFOyvlEI3KTF1mkBmMVBN4YwDGxdRv12okUJX8JG4yy6HnHKWSKI@Y3zlH8is2QSiEHMkhH5wYPBSyQywhIi4uiNkgeTO/NqSKzBu@iViZtbozi3I0flNUP3ypSRMrHOl@rm6Khci5au1PDqa/obI7fuLRhOs5kgAcmmY0REHA0N2SAQKf9PXqorXq5VlwtUX1b7juVyRVpxC@Fw6x0MpzLWQV93Ru@hbJ02xfxgHh1aZhVb9g5Sz0hE4rmmPKrO/GNXIC1veOthJ@70NeUh1pWQI3dCK2cm1@VRrJPPRIjFe7fgTEQ3uWG3F3PY9yxICN6eYvWzJBN8NhAsTfY6YhAHaKVuCZHmyCMTzxi4L7NaJHN/nPxbYx5lcMKkCpn@qGJOaPad3Zesa2D1Cw)
Song so far:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
```

Next line: `Gotta make you understand`

The roll continues...

Comment: \*sigh* you broke it.

Comment: @Makonede Sorry, got mixed up :P

Answer (score 1):

## Day 5 (x2)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 190 bytes

```python
print("""We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling""")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc47DoMwEATQnlOMaAApTcgJUnKCKKUVlk@wd5G9jsXpiUFJORrN06ybTsK3fV/9zFqXZfmgyhNYENQbHskHqMDKh4qnRCwsCToRfLQUYLhHEPSCrrhjiNbiJc7N6oi1CkiTUXSVy5OZl5lHyHA6SaLtuVKMpEcZMHhx2dsgmfcY41Z0eMegSIbZQCnjW55O@cFBDkQ2i/nz772pr5e2aYp/as@0fwE)

There's a (x2) in the answer since there's two possible answers this could continue off, and I need that sweet, sweet multi-answer.

Line for Day 6: `Gotta make you understand`

(we're so close)

Comment: It's `Gotta make you understand` - Sorry if my mix-up made you mix it up...

Answer (score 1):

## Day 5. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 90 bytes. My score: \$9.44\$

```
“We're€¸æÊs€„„Î
Youƒ€€€‰ï€ƒ€Ê€· I
A‚è©—'s€À I'm™Ð€‚
You€Þn't€Õ€Œ€š€Æ€¶ïí
I‚‰ÅËˆœ€î€ß I'm¥ª
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOc8FT1otRHTWsO7Ti87HBXMZD1qGEeEB3u44rMLz02CSQAQQ0bDq8H0mChw10gLdsVPLkcHzXMOrzi0MpHDVPUQboPNyh4quc@all0eAJY0yyQMSDxeXnqJSB6KpA4CjLj6EIQtw1k0LbD6w@v5fIEqgbZ0nq4@3Tb0ckg2XUgYj7IxENLD636/x8A)

[**Previous answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224898/94066)

Line for next day: `Gotta make you understand`

Song:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
```

---

```
“...  # trimmed program
“...  # push "We're no strangers to love\nYou know the rules and so do I\nA full commitment's what I'm thinking of\nYou wouldn't get this from any other guy\nI just wanna tell you how I'm feeling"
      # (implicit) end compressed string
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Day 6, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 189 bytes

```
⟦⪫Ｅ313…side to ×Ｉι⁴, ⟧Ｆ²⁺…Oh-u-⊗⁺ι⁶ “P➙⭆BＸ5↶÷ρ⦄⟧⁸A>ιZ›➙πα⊗σ*7¹´$⁹“ＢzＩ⊞³⌈”× la⁸“[¶²/;pv﹪ＨD⦃»ⅉδE4pＰf·⁹E”⪫Ｅ³… round and¹⁶,¦⸿It won't be long⪫Ｅ³ yeah (yeah)¦,⪫⪪“Z⧴aC¿Jy⌈←*üYlΦθd;hＡ⊗Ｕ±”¶¦ catchy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc9da8IwFAbg@/2Kl9yYQL1wDhnssjJwMCbo3bqLYxubQExKPlb667toQecYhEBOzvskp1bka0dmHLde28g/35y2/J06zpaLJStQDrWRpXK5EHQjER1yda9PMvCSQuRaFHgSIu@5zsSXeHk4Og/@KDCRW5Ny6435UPM0z71rlw5GNtO9LrCakGxkYoqyzeyEIxmjbVv5tbPoJazr4ZJHSwOo68hLU@CV2DU1fY7BUH7l@ZdW@b2S6JWUJiBjMZ8OKaB1t/B1/uXd7PAu2QZkm2wuVtO47M7eRPTOziIOEsbZ9n@TYZCkwM@7YH@ZS@euM/oi7lxli7yg4ywgpFqBKotwxnOwspc8aoq1Gs7KOI7zb/MD) Link is to verbose version of code. Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
```

Next line:

```
Please don't be long (don't be long)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Day 6. [Picolisp](https://picolisp.com), <s>251</s> 250 bytes

<sub>-1 byte because anonymous functions can take all arguments into an array with `@`</sub>

(for reference the song is 300 bytes so far)

```lisp
'[@(text"@1, side, @1
@2@2Oh @2@2Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa@3@3@3@3@3@3@3@3
The wheels on the bus go@4,@4,@4
It won't be long@5,@5,@5
So@6,@6, it's such a@6 song""side to side"'Oh-u-" la"" round and round"" yeah (yeah)"" catchy"]
```

Anonymous function that returns a string. [Jdoodle it!](https://jdoodle.com/ia/d8S)

#### Next line

`fried butter fried butter don't flag me fried butter` ([source](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=57822360#57822360))

#### Song so far

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
```

[previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224954/90614)

Comment: Just because you say it's a catchy song, it doesn't mean it's actually a catchy song :P

Comment: @user No, it's secretly ironic.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 7. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 116 bytes. My score: \$9\frac{13}{49}\$

```
“We're€¸æÊs€„„Î
Youƒ€€€‰ï€ƒ€Ê€· I
A‚è©—'s€À I'm™Ð€‚
You€Þn't€Õ€Œ€š€Æ€¶ïí
I‚‰ÅËˆœ€î€ß I'm¥ª
Gotta‚§€îíŒ
Neverº¢†¿€î€¾
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOc8FT1otRHTWsO7Ti87HBXMZD1qGEeEB3u44rMLz02CSQAQQ0bDq8H0mChw10gLdsVPLkcHzXMOrzi0MpHDVPUQboPNyh4quc@all0eAJY0yyQMSDxeXnqJSB6KpA4CjLj6EIQtw1k0LbD6w@v5fIEqgbZ0nq4@3Tb0ckg2XUgYj7IxENLD63ics8vKUkEqjq0HCx5eO3RSVx@qWWpRYd2HVr0qGHBof0wTYf2/f8PAA)

[**Previous answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225037/94066)

Line for next day: `Never gonna let you down`

Song:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
Never gonna give you up
```

---

```
“...  # trimmed program
“...  # push song
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Day 7,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 380 bytes

```
L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\u\rZ\gN\yZN\p\pN\rPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{\rL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wLQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\gZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
R{\f\r\iP\dZ\b\uTTP\r}RZRZ\dLQ\'TZ\fON\gZ\mPZR
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225078/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVtb6JAEP7Or9jwpXpXGzG5JtfUS6qntQkCAp/W8QMF1M0pkBXrmc3@dm9QfK3ovfTGRBl23p5nZ8ZkmY7jqLZKeDwidcJVVV3pAmLZFTCWhgBPmgIm0hIQyp6ASDoCZtIVkMon0RAOMAgs2aACiKSuThuyKeCWyqdmo/kEii1aoi3A7Mo2VGAuW1CRtt2mtt2i8AI3MKUwNEwTWA9GoMB3vUdhYdGeDguqwxw4hZEBS2pAAokB3DKb0DaeBTUN@ZwL@rkwttARvy3ToRjE7aL@CnMH/XXaEcAxWg8CaYsONfCBdqTdxA86v7joqvfgBn9fLWri4yhzWVoGkpA5QKkD5Z29o1NbgG@44HdhuX4NzIUbhzpYsd@l4FGbOvoaEloOgQOzMGVWkOtawKWNBhDkOYemgQlhalF7hRegKGyaxDwls@VMQZmGU7yavqoOyCdSu1eUxZhNQjIJo1J2bWXyjVQfFILChiTmwfptvzrAgzq5/0K8KDh@/VgnX3OPTN4welXZqQzV2k4LUNN2WoRaVuDOdnhUhrYPmp@uc2oDUkc/oR4fZ7KBEuwhnArGYORxn@W81ba2iHzepGQDpdBwWxbblAWgFgfdEsIwsHbZ6rcLLSr4km04mYXXIyacRSlRW5zH/JbMo6mX@mMWjcgr9/wfYTojLCLpOFyn5N70Tr0aEnvwLvzJ0lJZKa7thFFxjdCDNmWkQrTzrbo9OmnXIsk6Nbh6TX9D5I69BcNtOU@JR2bJBC1CjoQGzPfSmP8nLuUVLjeoKwWoL6P9wHa5Aq14hHC59Y@WUwX7YJBNRv@hor0firejfXRMmVZM2QdAPQMRE79lKU@6M/8zLYCWD7z2sAf3/pryEJtOyC33QKtnNtflVZwVP0sDbN67BWdpWMoJK1@s4ZAzLyLonWD3s2iW8rmfsjg6mAh/7CGV2UikcW55QuIZAg9h1opgHq6TfxvMkwreZZKFmf6oY96lOWT2EHLWA6tf)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
fried butter fried butter don't flag me fried butter
```

Next line: `Galileo Galileo Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o`

Answer (score 1):

## Day 8,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 360 bytes

```
O{\
}\WP{\g}A{\e}A\'G{\r}GAC{\ }CH{\o}N{\n}NHCJ{\s}JT{\t}TGZ{\a}ZNPAGJCTHCX{\l}XH\vAO\YV{HU{\u}UC}V\kNH\wF{T\h}CFACGUXAJCZN\dCJHC\dHC\IO\AC\fUXXC\cHM{\m}MM\iTMANT\'JC\w\hZTC\I\'MCF\iN\kY{\iNP}YCH\fO\YV\wHUX\dN\'TCPATCF\iJC\fGHMCZN\yCHFAGCPU\yO\IC\jUJTC\wZNNZCTAXXC\yV\hH\wC\I\'MC\fAAXYO\GHTTZCMZ\kAC\yVUN\dAGJTZN\dS{O\NA\vAGCPHNNZC}SP\i\vAC\yVU\pSXATC\yV\dH\wN
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225089/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVti9pAEP6eX7Hki3dtPcxBD3qchbDUpIJRuOQa4/ghNfGyVROJUSvL/nY7q/HdaF@uAyLjzs48z7Mz43iRRUl8vxynySupklRV1WWTgyLgW4vDq9A5hEKHksEhFYZOORBBTQ6JsDjEwjJpncNE1G0OmbANj4MvPKulG3Vqm9TlMBSuCTO9Ce0XbjocpsKh4gUGlgnzGrchErSmU8Nx9Tr1LAho3aQQ4OdrE3QKfcd1KfTMBoeRaDSA2Q3dsqFUpzCHyLMxDkoNWgNmwaDN8asl2tSEviwIc9NxIbCgZNOWbssovNc3zIYstaBmTTdoy4FFE75S@OHUMd3csyyP2rosu3iBCGHmNaCv6267CYZp2x5teDDQZYiDoJGuLcE/8yZYOtLFtKbMI55bwNBfBcL42UUUMm2Aaa0liq0obDRO0oxMFhMFbRSO8Bk6qtol78j9g6LMIzYMyTCMb@QT3ZLPpPKoEDTWJ0karH7tVLp4UCUPH4kfB4c/P1XJp/yGtBlmryhbl6F7v/UC9LStF6MnAW5j@wcwtF3S/HRVU@uSKt7j6uGxtDWVYEfh2DAHI0@7KuejNthi8n5dknWVwsANLLaGBaAWJ90IwjCxdjnqt4EWAb4UGw4n4fWM45TFGVG/pGmSfiDTeORnvYjFr@R76vcGYTYhLCZZFK5Kpv7oTr2aEnvwLvzJsptbpRjbkaL8mqB7bcpImWjnW3VzdNSuRSY7Nbj6TH8j5Fa9OcPNOM2ITybjIUaEKQoasJ6fJel/0lJc0XLNulzA@jLbN2yXK9SKRwiXW@dgOZWxD7pyMjqPZe10KGYH@@hQMq1YsjegeoYiFp7Jkkfdmf9xFlDLB1573JE7faY8xboT8sgd0cqZzXV5FUvwkyzA5r2bpywLb3LBbi9i2NfMjwneHmP3s3iSpdNexpJ4byJ6kY9SypHIkjzySMQzAu7TvC@iub9O/m0wjxCcVBKFlf6oY07K7Cu7T1n2wPIX)

Song so far:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
Never gonna give you up
Never gonna let you down
```

Next line: `Never gonna run around and desert you`

Note: These are written by hand.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 8

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 265 bytes

```python
print("""We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
Never gonna give you up
Never gonna let you down""")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY8xTsUwEER7n2KUJlBzgl@hNLSI0iKbxMTejex1rJw@rL9oaGf03s4el27Cb/d95MD6MgzDJ42ZwIKi2fNKuUAFUU5yX1KxszToRsg1UoHnGUUwCyb3wFJjxLekFDQR61jQNq@YxmRI4D3wClmeniY1zjwqVtJeFixZkvkuiOkz1nq5CT@1KJpn9lAy@WXoZgu6ciGKZnTvouqR/E7PuvJso9WWuQ86u0k6vobzrz/@5dHu93iWxvb@633/Ag)

Sorry for missing Day 7, but I'm back with the roll. (we made it)

Day 9's line: `Never gonna run around and desert you`

Comment: For day 9, you can definitely optimise the `Never gonna`s. I will keep the rickroll alive.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 8, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 226 bytes

```
⟦⪫Ｅ313…side to ×Ｉι⁴, ⟧Ｆ²⁺…Oh-u-⊗⁺ι⁶ “P➙⭆BＸ5↶÷ρ⦄⟧⁸A>ιZ›➙πα⊗σ*7¹´$⁹“ＢzＩ⊞³⌈”× la⁸“[¶²/;pv﹪ＨD⦃»ⅉδE4pＰf·⁹E”⪫Ｅ³… round and¹⁶,¦⸿It won't be long⪫Ｅ³ yeah (yeah)¦,⪫⪪“Z⧴aC¿Jy⌈←*üYlΦθd;hＡ⊗Ｕ±”¶¦ catchy⪫⟦⸿Please ¦ (¦)⸿A⟧don't be long×a³⁵h!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHNasMwEITvfYqpLpHBOaRuS6GnklBIoTSQ3OIcFFuxBIpkJLnGT@9ubMgfBbFIq51PO6tCCV84Yfp@5bWNfPvltOXfouYsm2UsxbwrjJwrR4mgS4noQNmNPsrA5yJErpMUz0lCkfIs2SXvDwfnwZ8SjMiVaaj0gvlR02ZKtQvX7I0sx3ud4nWEEIMQo5QtJ0cchDHaVrlfOItWwroWrvGoRAdR18JLk@JTsLNqbI7BCHrl7YqW@42SaJWUJoBgkU77JqByF/HZf3bjHd41toSwJTFnr6NddsNeRrTOTiL2EsbZ6n8mQyeFAj/FhN1jhsp1bfRAXLvcprSg4yQgNIWCyC3CCU7C3A56FCIWqrunbAmwMlIEOXwM@PA9uf9gO9qUt53ez@40uezlyp56JDt9309/zR8) Link is to verbose version of code. Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
```

Next line:

```
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
```

Answer (score 1):

## Day 9,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 377 bytes

```
O{\
}\WD{\d}P{\g}A{\e}A\'G{\r}GAC{\ }CH{\o}N{\n}NHCJ{\s}JT{\t}TGZ{\a}ZNPAGJCTHCX{\l}XH\vAO\YV{HU{\u}UC}VW{C\yV}\kNH\wF{T\h}CFACGUXAJCZNDCJHCDHC\IO\AC\fUXXC\cHM{\m}MM\iTMANT\'JC\w\hZTC\I\'MCF\iN\kY{\iNP}YCH\fO\YV\wHUXDN\'TCPATCF\iJC\fGHMCZN\yCHFAGCPU\yO\IC\jUJTC\wZNNZCTAXXW\hH\wC\I\'MC\fAAXYO\GHTTZCMZ\kAWUNDAGJTZNDS{O\NA\vAGCPHNNZC}SP\i\vAWU\pSXATWDH\wNSGUNCZGHUNDCZNDCDAJAGTW
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225159/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXbbtpAEH33V6z8QtKWCJAaqVGotFqKHSQMEnYwZnhwwYQtYCNjoGi1307HYO4YeknnBY13duacszPDZBkNAr@wmoTBGymSUFXVVU2AIqFZEtCTdQFvkgrwJIWMJiCUGmUCiGS6gEAaAnxp6KwiYCorpoBImpojwJWOUadahZk6swWMpK3DnNag9Sp0S8BMWky@NgWD5auEoaHDoixMGEhWpkyzbFphjlFiFZ2VdAYvNaAM@pZtM@jqVQFjWa0CN6vUMCFTYbCAgWNiHGSqrAzcgGFL4E9dtpgO/bgqLHTLLhmQMVmdmnEQXutrehXrwJLpZaqxugXLGrww@GFVMNvCMQyHmdS2mzBAgEl@6FNqt2qg6abpsKoDQ9q0jBJyNRFyQ9TAoEgV0@nxfdmoA0e/acGkYVOzWcJURkOzDOZoOl5cEy3RCtXM5grVVxQ@ngRhRKbLqYI29sb4Lm1V7ZAPpPCoKIsBH3lk5Pl38Zvdk68k96QQNN4nQdhbf23nOnhQJI@fiev3jj8/F8mX5EZsc8yeU3YuR7ew83ro5Xeej14McBfbP4KR3ydNTtc18x1SxHtCPT6ObUOlt6dwapiDk@d9lctRW2w@@bgpyTtKauAWFt/AAlDTk24F4Zg4fz3qt4GmAb4W642m3u2Mk5D7EVG/hWEQfiIzf@xG3QH338j30O0OvWhKuE@igbcuGbrjB/VmSuzBB@8nj@7ulXRsJ4qKW4IetCknWZK/3Krbo5N2TbO4U3s3n@lvhNypt@C4KmcRccl0MsIIL0RBe7zrRkH4n7SUN7TcsM6msL7O9h3b5Qa19BHC5dY@Wk5Z7INOPBntp2z@fCjmR/voWLJ8umTvQPUCRSw8j0uedGfyT5pCLRn4/NOe3PkzJSk2nZBE7onmLmyu66s4Bj@Neti8D4uQR95dItj9VQyHmrk@wdsT7H7uT6Nw1o144B9MRHfgopTxSERBEnki4gUBD2kW0mgerpN/G8wTBGeVZGqlP@qYszKHyh5Sjntg9Qs)

Song so far:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
Never gonna give you up
Never gonna let you down
Never gonna run around and desert you
```

Next line: `Never gonna make you cry`

Answer (score 1):

## Day 9,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 450 bytes

```
L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\u\rZ\gN\yZN\p\pN\rPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{\rL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNO\iOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\F\i\gN\rLZ\MN\gQ\i\f\i\cN{L\-}NNNNL
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225166/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVXbbtpAEH33V2z9ktCGCCI1UqNQCQiESMY2Nk/L8ODYDqwKtrWYULTab6ezYO4YekkHYXl253bOzo6TeTqMo7tFwuMBqRCu6/rCEBDLtoChNAV40hIwkraAUHYERNIVMJFdAamsippwgUFgyxoVQCTtGrQm6wJuqKzWa/UqaI5oiKYAqy2bUISpbEBROk6TOk6DwgtcwZjCm2lZwDowAA2ejA6FmU07BsyoAVPgFAYmzKkJCSQmcNuqQ9N8FtQy5XMm6NeFoY2O@LQtl2KQbhv1V5i66G/QlgCO0ToQSEe0qIkvtCWdOv7Q@aWLrk/C6MAVvr3a1MLXgXxSbnPbRCKUE1y3oLDxcQ3qCPDNLvhtmC@XgXXhyqUuVu23KXjUoa6xgmVbtunayiN4kg6GcqCAy1VHmEpkSzjq2Wo5Ths@Kdrg2URSLNvAvaU5depogL5NpBwp4QaFtgmDDqpv@PdNYSC5KpyxwGPUNDZOYp6SyXyioYzDMR5wT9f75DO5u9e02ZCNQjIKo2t1@AXynZQeNILC3kjMg@Vqr9THjQq5/0q8KNhffqyQb5mHkneMXtI2KkP1bqMFqJU3WoSaKnBj@7ZXRnkbNNtd5iz3SQX9hL6/rWQFJdhCOBSMwcjjNstpq3VtEfmySsn6Wq7huiy2KgtAzw@6JoRh4PJ5q98uNK/gc7bhaBJejphwFqVEb3Ae8xsyjcZe6g9ZNCCv3PN/hOmEsIikw3CZknvjW/1iSOzB2/AnS68LWn5tB4yKS4TutCkjRVI@3arrrYN2zRPVqcHFY/obIjfszRjO3GlKPDJJRmgRciQ0YL6Xxvw/cSkvcLlCXcxBfR7tB7bLBWj5VwiHW29vOBWxD/rqZvQeiuXjS/G@N4/2KSvnU/YBUE9AxMTvKuVBd2af5Bxo2YUvP2zBHR9TFmLVCZnlFmjpxOQ6P4pV8ZM0wOa9nXGWhtcZYYWzNexy5kUEvRPsfhZNUj71UxZHOzfCH3pIpboSaZxZHpB4gsBdmHd5MHfHyb9dzIMKjjLJ3Ex/1DFHaXaZ3YWsemDxCw)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
```

Next line: `99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer`

Comment: Missed an opportunity for `magnifico! I'm just a poor boy nobody loves me` :(

Comment: @ophact More than one person can continue an answer if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 10, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 305 bytes

```
⟦⪫Ｅ313…side to ×Ｉι⁴, ⟧Ｆ²⁺…Oh-u-⊗⁺ι⁶ “P➙⭆BＸ5↶÷ρ⦄⟧⁸A>ιZ›➙πα⊗σ*7¹´$⁹“ＢzＩ⊞³⌈”× la⁸“[¶²/;pv﹪ＨD⦃»ⅉδE4pＰf·⁹E”⪫Ｅ³… round and¹⁶,¦⸿It won't be long⪫Ｅ³ yeah (yeah)¦,⪫⪪“Z⧴aC¿Jy⌈←*üYlΦθd;hＡ⊗Ｕ±”¶¦ catchy⪫⟦⸿Please ¦ (¦)⸿A⟧don't be long×a³⁵⪫⪪“T⊞8⁻‖⟧e2ü"↑«℅γ“=βk²↨r⊟h‹⬤ＢY=⁰”¶¦Galileo…o-⁹⸿Ｆ²⁺× on the wall, ι”- ⊟d⌈Pï⌊;∕1/↖⍘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJNa@MwEIbv@yve1SU2OIdutqWhp5LSpQtlA@2t7mFiK5ZA1QRJXpNf747t3TQJASOk8cwz73xUhkLF5Pp@HaxP2dtvtj57pl2mFlcLVWC1r5xeGRZDtLVGYoj11X7omK0opszmBX7muZxiV/l7fvdtywHZjxwTcu1acf3C/DHzdi6@D9xunK6n/7bAzQQRhiCmUPU0@8CWnLO@KcMDe3QanjtwG9DQHrTbUdCuwCOpQ9QkTsGRZLk9opXh1Wh0RmsXIbAkr00b0fBX8KH@xUntCNz6GuRrYV7dTOWqE/ZTQsd@lrDRcOyby0yFvSaDbDhzdY4ZPV92zo7EFy59IR9smkXEtjKg0iMOcAks/RiPilJl9ueUNwGsnaaox8EgG8dThnv1Lpf6VOl574bOLa4v6zLfy5CVPseg7HARXY@2ocB4psbbra2OJP4iZ53mozxHreVhGZYnrVSXl@j/YP@NrpPFGLduWEG1XGLDKTkto91KZToM6fq@n/91nw) Link is to verbose version of code. Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
```

Next line:

```
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
```

Answer (score 1):

## Day 11,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 553 bytes

```
L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\u\rZ\gN\yZN\p\pN\rPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{\rL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNO\iOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\F\i\gN\rLZ\MN\gQ\i\f\i\cR{L\-}RRRRL\
R{\9\9Z\bLTTOPSZL\fZ\bPP\r}RZLQZT\hPZ\wNOOCR\
R{\NLC\yL\uZ\cNQ\'T\.Z}H{B{\YPSC\IZ\cNQ}B\.Z}RHRHRBCB\!
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225297/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVbb9owFH7Pr/Dy0rKVqlRapVbtpJKWUikkwcnL3MNDmgSwBgkyoQxZ/u3dMaTcSmCX7iBQjn1u35fPZjTL@1l6/joSWY/cEGGa5qstIVMtCX3lSAiVK2GgPAmJaktIlS9hrAIJubqVdekDh9hTdSaBKBbYrK4sCSdM3Vp16xYMKu9lQ4LbUg2owkTdQ1VR2mCU3jN4hCMYMug6rgu8DT0w4M5uM5h6rG3DlNkwAcGg58CMOTCCkQPCcy1oOA@SuY56KAzzAuh7mIi/nuszLBK00H@GiY/5NmtKEFitDbGisskcfGBNRS38YPJjgKl30m7DET49e8zFx56602kzz0EidBIcN6GyzPFtRiVETgBRC2bzZeABHPnMx6mjFoOQUebbC1ie6zm@pzPiO0WxFIUKLt9S6WhTTUn1b7NJaQs@adrgwUFSXM/GvXk4oxYGYG4DKUdKhM2g5UCvjW4XvxGV9pxcSu15gUu4RDB2ELgeMgJdjcwDge01PQu@kHmNBqMd24IZUsQQk@YBThl2rkv47vkWPM6XVV2v0iZ@6lYdPr2iWgyDD0eZyMl4NjbQhskQdfRkmh3ymZxfGMa0zwcJGSTpsdZYhXwjZ1cGQeNdkol4vvp01sGNG3LxlYRpvLl8fUMuiwxtL1j9zFi6HN3zpRejV1t6KXp6wGVsd2OM2qposTvvWeuQG8yT5ua2tgWUeAVh27AGJ9erLruj3mZLyZdFS94xSgPfxuKLsQDM8qJvhHAsXNsf9duDlg28LzYZjJPDFUeCpzkx74XIxAmZpMMwj/o87ZFnEUY/knxMeEryfjJvKcLhqXmwJGrwNPnJ8@OKUT7bFqPyEKFrMuWkSmq7pfq2tSXXMtNKjQ@@pr8hcsnelOPVPslJSMajAUYkAgmNeRTmmfhPXKoDXC5QV0tQ70f7gXI5AK38COHl9rRxOVVRBx19Mp6uqrX3h@Jl4z7apKxWTtkHQN0BERu/6JZb6iz@@UugFQe@drUC9/41FSUWSigiV0DPdtxc@69iPfw4j1G8p1PB8@S4IKyyd4Z1zsKUYPYI1c/TcS4mUc6zdO1ERP0QqdRHIs@KyC0SdxC4DvO8DOb6dfJvB3NrgnedVGmnP1LMuzbrzK5D1hp4/QU)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
```

Next line: `No no no no no no no! Mama mia Mama mia Mama mia let me go`

Answer (score 1):

## Day 11. Scala, 476 bytes. Score = 57

```scala
_=>{val(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)=("side to side","Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh"," round and round"," yeah (yeah)"," catchy","don't be long","(Galileo) Galileo,","99 bottles of beer","No, you can't."," Yes, I can")
s"$a, side, $a\n$b $b-u I'm falling\nDon we now our gay apparel, Fa${" la"*8}\nThe wheels on the bus go$c,$c,$c\nIt won't be long$d,$d,$d\nSo$e,$e, it's such a$e song\nPlease $f ($f)\nA${"a"*34}h!\n$f $f Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o\n$h on the wall, $h\n${s"$i$j. "*2}$i$j,$j!"}
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GWstbfBhTfykPfUI0i78LA)

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225297/95792)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
don't be long don't be long Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
```

Line for tomorrow: `If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!`

Comment: Might want to mark it as scala (assuming it is)

Comment: @Wezl Oops, thanks for reminding me

Comment: Why did you join *after* the rickroll died?

Comment: You need a comma after the Nos.

Comment: There's supposed to be a comma after the `No`, so you "fixed" my answer incorrectly. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Neil My bad, it's fixed now

Comment: @Ausername I wouldn't have joined if I'd known you'd answer this, I just want to keep the answers going, even though this question turned out to be a flop :P

Comment: Very nice, catchy song, right? My English teacher says a lot of repetition is good.

Comment: @user It's fine. Besides, it gives me something to do for day 12.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 12,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 604 bytes

```
L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\u\rZ\gN\yZN\p\pN\rPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{\rL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNO\iOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\F\i\gN\rLZ\MN\gQ\i\f\i\cR{L\-}RRRRL\
A{\9\9Z\bLTTOPSZL\fZ\bPP\r}AZLQZT\hPZ\wNOOCA\
R{\NLC\yL\uZ\cNQ\'T\.Z}H{B{\YPSC\IZ\cNQ}B\.Z}RHRHRBCB\!\
\I\fZ\IZR{T\r\yC}RRR\IZ\cNQZR{\d\r\iQ\k}RCRCRZA\!
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225312/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVZbb@I4FH7Pr/DkpWV3qEqlHanVdCVIS6kUkuDkZd3DQ5oEsAYSZEJZZPm3d4@TlFsJ7GXWiCjHPrfv82fDfJ1PsvTmfS6yMbknwjTNd1tCpvoSJsqRECpXwlR5EhI1kJAqX8JCBRJy1ZYd6QOH2FMdJoEoFtisoywJX5lqWx2rDQaVj7Irwe2rLjRhqR6hqSjtMkofGTzDBcwYjBzXBT6AMRjwYA8YrDw2sGHFbFiCYDB2YM0cmMPcAeG5FnSdJ8lcRz1VA@MCmHgYiE/P9RkmCfpov8LSx3ib9SQIzDaAWFHZYw6@sJ6iFn4w@DnA0AdpD@AC31495uLrWD3osLXnIBE6CC570NjE@DajEiIngKgP62IaeAAXPvOx66jPIGSU@XYJy3M9x/d0RPygKKai0MDpNpWOHqonqX72epT24YumDZ4cJMX1bFwr3Bm10AFju0g5UiJsBn0HxgM0R/iNqLQLcim1wWhLuIVbBGMHgeshIzDSyDwQql3QU/KFzJe7BI5twRopYohJ8wBXDCt3JPzh@RY8F9Oqo2dpDz8dq6P7xC3EvM8ILAABa0uXr5wLsDiJG/ujZI214cs7Csww@GyeiZws1gsDxyyZofReTHNIfiE33wxjNeHThEyT9FLLskF@J9d3BsHBRyQTcTH7cj3EhXvy7TcSpvH@9Pd7cltF6PGG2a@NjcnRvNlYMVqtjZWipRvc@I722mhtk1arRc3WkNxjnDT3l/UoocRbCIcDc3DyfVvluNdHbyn5tSzJh0at40dbvGwLwKxP@kEIx8St015/u9G6hk/5JtNFcj7jXPA0J@ajEJn4SpbpLMyjCU/H5FWE0Y8kXxCeknySFCVFOLsyz6ZEDV4lf/L8smHU93bAqDxH6I5MOWmS1nGpfiwdyLVuaKXGZ7fp3xC5YW/F8ddgmZOQLOZT9EgEEhrzKMwz8T9xqc5wWaJu1qA@jfYnyuUMtPojhJfby97l1EQdDPXJeLlrtj4fire9@2ifslY9ZT8B6hGIWPhNlzxQZ/VnoQZadeBbd1twn7epSlEqofLcAr0@cnOdvop184s8RvFerQTPk8uKsMbJHnY5C1OC0XNUP08XuVhGOc/SnRMRTUKkUh@JPKs8D0g8QuAuzJs6mLvXyX87mAcdfKqkaiv9I8V8KrPL7C5krYH3vwA)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
```

Next line: `Wo-o-o-o-o-o-oah, Wo-o-o-o-o-o-oah`

Answer (score 1):

## Day 12, Vyxal, 656 bytes

[Try it online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60side%20to%20side%2C%20side%2C%20side%20to%20side%0AOh-u-Oh-u-Oh%20Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u%20I%27m%20falling%0ADon%20we%20now%20our%20gay%20apparel%2C%20Fa%20la%20la%20la%20la%20la%20la%20la%20la%0AThe%20wheels%20on%20the%20bus%20go%20round%20and%20round%2C%20round%20and%20round%2C%20round%20and%20round%0AIt%20won%27t%20be%20long%20yeah%20%28yeah%29%2C%20yeah%20%28yeah%29%2C%20yeah%20%28yeah%29%0ASo%20catchy%2C%20catchy%2C%20it%27s%20such%20a%20catchy%20song%0APlease%20don%27t%20be%20long%20%28don%27t%20be%20long%29%0AAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!%0A%28Galileo%29%20Galileo%2C%20%28Galileo%29%20Galileo%2C%20Galileo%20Figaro%20Magnifico-o-o-o-o%0A99%20bottles%20of%20beer%20on%20the%20wall%2C%2099%20bottles%20of%20beer%0ANo%2C%20you%20can%27t.%20Yes%2C%20I%20can.%20No%2C%20you%20can%27t.%20Yes%2C%20I%20can.%20No%2C%20you%20can%27t.%20Yes%2C%20I%20can%2C%20Yes%2C%20I%20can!%0AIf%20I%20try%2C%20try%2C%20try%2C%20I%20can%20drink%2C%20drink%2C%20drink%2099%20bottles%20of%20beer!%60%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
`side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!`,
```

The rickroll died, but I will revive it. Day 13's line: `We're no strangers to love`.

Comment: I was able to compress it down to 389 bytes. I can't seem to figure out how to make it work in a comment, so I'll post it as a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 12, [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 377 bytes

```
⟦⪫Ｅ313…side to ×Ｉι⁴, ⟧Ｆ²⁺…Oh-u-⊗⁺ι⁶ “P➙⭆BＸ5↶÷ρ⦄⟧⁸A>ιZ›➙πα⊗σ*7¹´$⁹“ＢzＩ⊞³⌈”× la⁸“[¶²/;pv﹪ＨD⦃»ⅉδE4pＰf·⁹E”⪫Ｅ³… round and¹⁶,¦⸿It won't be long⪫Ｅ³ yeah (yeah)¦,⪫⪪“Z⧴aC¿Jy⌈←*üYlΦθd;hＡ⊗Ｕ±”¶¦ catchy⪫⟦⸿Please ¦ (¦)⸿A⟧don't be long×a³⁵⪫⪪“T⊞8⁻‖⟧e2ü"↑«℅γ“=βk²↨r⊟h‹⬤ＢY=⁰”¶¦Galileo…o-⁹⸿Ｆ²⁺× on the wall, ι”- ⊟d⌈Pï⌊;∕1/↖⍘”⸿⪫Ｅ..,!⁺⁺×No, you can't. ‹!ιYes, I canι ¦⸿N…o n¹⁹!× Mama mia³ let me go
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLfa9swEMff91dc9BIbnECXrSzsaaR0ZCxdoH0ZdR8uzsUWyLogyTP567OT3aZOGjBCOt997te3qNAVjOZ4XDttQ/L8i7VNVrhP1OxmpjJYHApDi4rF4PWWIDCI9UnX5JMF@pDoNIMvaSqn2FX6kn7/tGMHyecUeuTaNOL6jvlTTZqJ@N5xszG07f/rDG57iDAE0Yeq5biGHRqjbZm7O7bQElhugRsHJR4A93t0ZDK4R3WK6otTYFCyfBvQcvdUEbQVkfEgsCCvTeOh5PfgU/@zs97BcWO3gHYrzJvbvl11xl4GaNmOA2wIDNvyOlPBgbCCJJ6pusR0no97ozviI@c2kw90GHvwTVEB5hZ8hEtgbrt4KDAU1eGS8iyAtSH01C0Gkm49ufuhXuSyPa/0cnZxcrOv1@uqRrlLcptCrOx0kbrudYmOYYWl1TtdDEr8iUYb4kGewWg5imF@Nkp1XURvi31dXSvC6FQXJajmc9hwCIZktTvpjJz6wLxYh5pOs5HEd/BhhgfO4MCNTFamNI0pfpMX@6hLFrP9JZ/BMjrEBvWbcgf5HtTVZsFGAQ3bHX1U7gprhFp3Wxh4gqEANfV6PR6Pk3/mPw) Link is to verbose version of code. Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
No no no no no no no! Mama mia Mama mia Mama mia let me go
```

Next line:

```
Never gonna give, never gonna give (Give you up)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Day 13,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 656 bytes

```
Y{\r}L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\uYZ\gN\yZN\p\pNYPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{YL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNO\iOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\F\i\gNYLZ\MN\gQ\i\f\i\cR{L\-}RRRRL\
A{\9\9Z\bLTTOPSZL\fZ\bPPY}AZLQZT\hPZ\wNOOCA\
R{\NLC\yL\uZ\cNQ\'T\.Z}H{B{\YPSC\IZ\cNQ}B\.Z}RHRHRBCB\!\
\I\fZ\IZR{TY\yC}RRR\IZ\cNQZR{\dY\iQ\k}RCRCRZA\!\
\NR{P\vPYZ\gLQQNZ\g\i\vP}RCQRZ\(\G\i\vPZ\yL\uZ\u\p\)
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225378/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVZbb@I4FH7Pr/DkpWVnqEqlHanVdCRIS6kUcnHyEvfwkJIA1kBAIcAiy7@9e5yk3EpgdmfGCMixz@37/NkwW2ejaXLzNkunQ3JPUl3X3wIBqTQFTGVXwEhaAkJpCxhLR0AsXQGJ9ATMpS8gk03REh5wiBzZYgKIZL7JWtIQ8IXJptEymqBR8SjaAuyubEMdFvIR6pLSNqP0kcEzXMCEwcCybeAuDEGDB9NlsHKYa8KKmbAIGAwtWDMLZjCzAsc2oG09CWZb8qkcGOXDyMEw/HRsj2EKv4v2Kyw8DDdZRwSYyoVIUtFhFj6wjqQGvjD22cfIB2G6cIFPrw6z8XEoHzAK1o6FLKgguOxAbRPjmYwK6Fs@9LuwzqeB@3DhMQ8WOMcgZJR5ZoHJsR3Lc1RE9CAppqJQw@kmFZYasiOo@ux0KO3CJ8UZPFnIiO2YuJa7M2qgA8a2ke@hFZgMuhYMXbQG@O5TYebEUmqC1hRwC7eIxfR920E@YKCAOYFs5twUZCHpxQaBZRqwRoIYIlIswBXDui0BgeMZ8JxPy5aapR18tYyW6hJ3D9M@Iyw/gLWhipe@OdJA7eiPgjHWzAMsKhxYOmpLTde18AtbXzro4ypW4Ck3WdnLAne89oai1DQ@mU3TjMzXcw3HJJ6gXF90vUf@IjdfNW014uOYjOPkUkm5Rr6T6zuN4OADMk2jfPbluocL9@Tr3yRMov3pb/fktoxQY4nZr7WNydG82VgRWo2NlaClGtz4DvbaaGyTlqt5zUaP3GOc0PeX1SigRFsIhwNzcPJtW@W413tvCflclOQ9rdLxvS1etAWgVyd9J4Rj4sZpr59utKrhU77xeB6fzzhLeZIR/TFNp@kXskgmYdYf8WRIXtOw/yPO5oQnJBvFeck0nFzpZ1OiBq/if3h2WdOqeztgVJwjdEemnNRJ47hU35cO5Fo1lFKjs9v0f4jcsLfi@AuyyEhI5rMxesQpEhrxfphN0z/EpTzDZYG6XoH6NNrfKJcz0KqPEF5uL3uXUx110FMn4@Wu3vh4KJZ799E@ZY1qyn4D1CMQsfBSlTxQZ/kHowJaeeAbd1twH7epTFEoofTcAr0@cnOdvopV8/MsQvFerVKexZclYbWTPexyFiYEo2eofp7Ms3TRz/g02TkR/VGIVKojkU1LzwMSjxC4C/OmCubudfJrB/Oggw@VZGWl/6SYD2V2md2FrDTw9i8)
Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
Never gonna give, never gonna give (Give you up)
```

Next line: `You are my SyntaxError, my only SyntaxError.`

Score: \$ 16\frac{131}{242} \$

Answer (score 1):

## Day 15,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 754 bytes

```
Y{\r}L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\uYZ\gN\yZN\p\pNYPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{YL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNO\iOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\F\i\gNYLZ\MN\gQ\i\f\i\cR{L\-}RRRRL\
A{\9\9Z\bLTTOPSZL\fZ\bPPY}AZLQZT\hPZ\wNOOCA\
R{\NLC\yL\uZ\cNQ\'T\.Z}H{B{\YPSC\IZ\cNQ}B\.Z}RHRHRBCB\!\
\I\fZ\IZR{TY\yC}RRR\IZ\cNQZR{\dY\iQ\k}RCRCRZA\!\
\NR{P\vPYZ\gLQQNZ\g\i\vP}RCQRZ\(\G\i\vPZ\yL\uZ\u\p\)
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225551/100664)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
Never gonna give, never gonna give (Give you up)
You are my SyntaxError, my only SyntaxError.
No juggernaut can stop us, no 4000
```

[Try it online!](https://deadfish.surge.sh/splinter#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)

Next line: `Na, na, na-na-na-na, na-na-na-na, hey Jude`

Comment: *can (in the last line)

Comment: @hyper-neutrino oops.

Answer (score 1):

## Day 15,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 727 bytes

```
Y{\r}L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\uYZ\gN\yZN\p\pNYPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{YL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNO\iOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\F\i\gNYLZ\MN\gQ\i\f\i\cR{L\-}RRRRL\
A{\9\9Z\bLTTOPSZL\fZ\bPPY}AZLQZT\hPZ\wNOOCA\
R{\NLC\yL\uZ\cNQ\'T\.Z}H{B{\YPSC\IZ\cNQ}B\.Z}RHRHRBCB\!\
\I\fZ\IZR{TY\yC}RRR\IZ\cNQZR{\dY\iQ\k}RCRCRZA\!\
\[\i\gQLYPZP\vPY\yT\h\iQ\gZ\bP\fLYPZT\h\iSZO\iQP\]\
\WP\'YPZQLZSTYNQ\gPYSZTLZOL\vP\
\YL\uZ\kQL\wZT\hPZY\uOPSZNQ\dZSLZ\dLZ\I
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225501/100664)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
[ignore everything before this line]
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
```

[Try it online](https://deadfish.surge.sh/splinter#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)

Next line: `A full commitment's what I'm thinking of`

Answer (score 1):

## Day 17,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 884 bytes

```
Y{\r}L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\uYZ\gN\yZN\p\pNYPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{YL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNO\iOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\F\i\gNYLZ\MN\gQ\i\f\i\cR{L\-}RRRRL\
A{\9\9Z\bLTTOPSZL\fZ\bPPY}AZLQZT\hPZ\wNOOCA\
R{\NLC\yL\uZ\cNQ\'T\.Z}H{B{\YPSC\IZ\cNQ}B\.Z}RHRHRBCB\!\
\I\fZ\IZR{TY\yC}RRR\IZ\cNQZR{\dY\iQ\k}RCRCRZA\!\
\NR{P\vPYZ\gLQQNZ\g\i\vP}RCQRZ\(\G\i\vPZ\yL\uZ\u\p\)\
\YL\uZNYPZ\m\yR{Z\S\yQTN\x\EYYLY}RC\m\yZLQO\yR\.\
\NLZ\j\u\g\gPYQN\uTZ\cLQZSTL\pZ\uSCQLZ\4\0\0\0\
\NNCR{QN}RCH{R\-}HHHRCHHHRC\hP\yZ\J\u\dP\
\IZ\uSP\dZTLZY\uOPZT\hPZ\wLYO\dC\c\h\uQ\kSZ\wL\uO\dZOLN\dZ\w\hPQZ\IZ\gN\vPZT\hPZ\wLY\d
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225678/100664)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
Never gonna give, never gonna give (Give you up)
You are my SyntaxError, my only SyntaxError.
No juggernaut con stop us, no 4000
Na, na, na-na-na-na, na-na-na-na, hey Jude
I used to rule the world, chunks would load when I gave the word
```

[Try it online](https://deadfish.surge.sh/splinter#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)

Next line: `You say yes I say no you say stop and I say go`

[image]

Graph of answers so far. click for bigger version.

Comment: I approve of this graph

Answer (score 0):

## Day 1. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes. My score: \$9\$

```
19LTK„, ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0NInxPtRwzwdhcN7//8HAA)

[**Previous answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224575/94066)

Line for next day: `�ꭙ`. Hexdump:

```
00000000: f18d b6bc f1b8 8380 f0b3 9781 f380 a8bf  ................
00000010: f29d 8aac f19b b7ae f3ab 9997 f2b9 859f  ................
00000020: f3b0 9ca5 f19b 80b6 f0b0 92a2 f1af 9b90  ................
00000030: f191 aead f3ba aaa5 f487 abab f2a0 88ac  ................
00000040: f29e a49c f387 8faa f2a7 b7b9 f3b7 b583  ................
00000050: f19a 9393 f09a 9d99 f094 8dac f3aa 8bb3  ................
00000060: f180 afbc f28e 8aa1 f3b4 9f81 f0a3 8e82  ................
00000070: f0a9 80a6 f1a4 8092 f291 bf85 f2b3 adb2  ................
00000080: f480 aa95 f184 91b9 f1ae 95bc f1b6 879c  ................
00000090: efbf bdf0 bba5 8cf0 a5ad aaf1 9f8c a8f0  ................
000000a0: b0b8 8ef3 a5b2 8df4 8782 baf2 819b 99f2  ................
000000b0: 9e92 8fea ad99 f0b6 918a f0b7 a19f f1a7  ................
000000c0: b7b3 f29a 8cbf f286 bd98 f286 85a6 f19a  ................
000000d0: 899b f19d aa93 f3bb b59c f2be b9b9 f18e  ................
000000e0: 9694 f3bc b6b0 f2bb ac9f f1a7 9eba f38e  ................
000000f0: b4bf f2a0 8792 f0bd bb9a f0a4 baae f29a  ................
00000100: ada5 f1b5 9c83 f3b9 b9a1 f1b6 84a8 f2b7  ................
00000110: aa81 f288 9db0 f195 9cbf f1ba 90a4 f3bc  ................
00000120: 97ab f09f bc81 f38f b4aa f399 aa8c f385  ................
00000130: b3af f1bd 9287 f3af 95a9 f182 899d f1ba  ................
00000140: a48d f487 a486 f2be 87af f1b7 b899 f2b1  ................
00000150: 909b f186 93b1 f09c 8092 f0bd aeb4 f299  ................
00000160: bf8b f48a 96be f2a6 b59b f1a8 9397 f0a9  ................
00000170: abab f1a1 a4bb f3a1 93a9 f1b5 b497 f2a8  ................
00000180: b0a2 f388 a39a f196 9783 f3aa aaa4       ..............
```

Song:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
```

---

```
19LTK„, ý  # full program
        ý  # join...
  L        # [1, 2, 3, ...,
19         # ..., literal...
  L        # ]...
    K      # excluding all...
   T       # 10...
    K      # s...
        ý  # by...
     „,    # literal
           # implicit output
```

Comment: Could you provide a hexdump for those bytes?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing All bytes are visible in the answer. None have been removed by SE.

Comment: @user I'll do it, thanks though.

Comment: There was no 10 in the original line, guess it was a trap!

Comment: @Kaddath Whoops! Fixed at the cost of 2 bytes XD

Comment: The line for the next day is too long

Comment: @pxeger Incorrect, it's 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Day 1. Scala, 37 bytes

```scala
_=>1 to 19 filter(10!=_)mkString ", "
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sVPcsJEaRka6MgbF129tPg)

**[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224575/95792)***

Song (NB this does not include 10):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
```

Line for next day: `bugs in my code, 19 freaking bugs`

Comment: As [Kaddath pointed out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224562/compose-a-song-line-by-line/224615?noredirect=1#comment520123_224615) on my answer, there is no \$10\$.

Answer (score 0):

## Day 2. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes. My score: \$5.75\$

```
“I'm€É…Ù‚º€Ÿ“∊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMcT/XcR01rDnc@alh2eOajhlmHdgG5R3cAZR51dP3/DwA)

[**Previous answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224667/94066)

Line for next day: `ᤴ헚`. Hexdump:

```
00000000: f291 aab8 f387 98b7 f1b1 98bc f2a4 a0bb  ................
00000010: f3b3 b290 f39e bcb0 f0bb b0b3 f189 9db3  ................
00000020: f387 8099 f294 a193 f48c 91a6 f098 839f  ................
00000030: f3bf beac f393 b2a3 e1a4 b4f2 a4ad 83f3  ................
00000040: 84aa 8ff1 9492 9ff4 808b b6f2 8e88 95f2  ................
00000050: 8eae 88f2 918d b7f3 9898 a4f2 9584 80f0  ................
00000060: a1ba bbf2 a7b0 bdf1 a8b8 86f1 8da6 9df1  ................
00000070: 91aa 9bf3 a690 b6f4 879f aef2 9ea7 99f2  ................
00000080: 8983 a0f1 a5b8 80f2 9b8d 84f0 b882 a2f1  ................
00000090: a3aa 9bf3 8fb5 85f1 a9a8 84f1 ada1 97f1  ................
000000a0: 8bbf b4f0 9d81 a7f0 a69b a5f2 b9b1 b7f1  ................
000000b0: b1b1 81f1 b8ac b7f1 a198 8af2 91a4 88f2  ................
000000c0: a69b bdf3 b0a5 8cf1 aebd abf2 94ac 91f0  ................
000000d0: 9ba4 b1f1 84a8 9df2 9d85 a3f2 848b 80f2  ................
000000e0: b58c 84f1 9fa5 8ff4 8ba7 a3f1 80b0 a2f3  ................
000000f0: 8997 b9f1 b9b3 bff3 82a6 80f2 9dbd baf1  ................
00000100: af86 80f3 b3be a3f4 888e 8ff2 ae9d 92f2  ................
00000110: a9ae b4f2 8c83 acf1 8187 9cf2 99aa b0f0  ................
00000120: b8ac a2f0 bdb2 97f3 bd92 a6f2 be98 adf3  ................
00000130: bba2 b2ef a087 f091 b6ae f2bd 8fb2 f383  ................
00000140: 988d f398 b991 f1a0 aeab f486 a1a3 f090  ................
00000150: b185 f191 acab f1ae a088 f3be abb5 f095  ................
00000160: ba94 f2a7 b1b5 f3a7 8aaf f0b7 b19b f1aa  ................
00000170: 9194 f2b6 9198 f1a9 808d f0b8 8397 f0b5  ................
00000180: a084 ed97 9af0 b995 aff0 9689 81         .............
```

Song:

```
I'm only human after all
I'm only human after all
```

---

```
“...“∊  # trimmed program
     ∊  # push...
“...“   # "I'm only human after all"...
     ∊  # vertically mirrored
        # implicit output
```

Comment: That line is too long. The maximum is 100 characters. And do you have to totally ruin the pattern, the golfing opportunity, and consequently the fun for everyone else?

Comment: You also answered yesterday, and you can't answer two days in a row. (Although your answer yesterday was also invalid because it's too long)

Comment: @pxeger You can't continue the same song two days in a row. You can answer two days in a row.

Comment: @pxeger I can answer two days in a row, I'm not continuing my own song. And this is 100 characters. It's longer in bytes, but it is exactly 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Day 6. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 102 bytes. My score: \$9\frac{7}{18}\$

```
“We're€¸æÊs€„„Î
Youƒ€€€‰ï€ƒ€Ê€· I
A‚è©—'s€À I'm™Ð€‚
You€Þn't€Õ€Œ€š€Æ€¶ïí
I‚‰ÅËˆœ€î€ß I'm¥ª
Gotta‚§€îíŒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOc8FT1otRHTWsO7Ti87HBXMZD1qGEeEB3u44rMLz02CSQAQQ0bDq8H0mChw10gLdsVPLkcHzXMOrzi0MpHDVPUQboPNyh4quc@all0eAJY0yyQMSDxeXnqJSB6KpA4CjLj6EIQtw1k0LbD6w@v5fIEqgbZ0nq4@3Tb0ckg2XUgYj7IxENLD63ics8vKUkEqjq0HCx5eO3RSf//AwA)

[**Previous answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224955/94066)

Line for next day: `Never gonna give you up`

Song:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
```

---

```
“...  # trimmed program
“...  # push "We're no strangers to love\nYou know the rules and so do I\nA full commitment's what I'm thinking of\nYou wouldn't get this from any other guy\nI just wanna tell you how I'm feeling\nGotta make you understand"
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Day 7,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 342 bytes

```
O{\
}\WP{\g}A{\e}A\'G{\r}GAC{\ }CH{\o}N{\n}NHCJ{\s}JT{\t}TGZ{\a}ZNPAGJCTHCX{\l}XH\vAO\YV{HU{\u}UC}V\kNH\wF{T\h}CFACGUXAJCZN\dCJHC\dHC\IO\AC\fUXXC\cHM{\m}MM\iTMANT\'JC\w\hZTC\I\'MCF\iN\kY{\iNP}YCH\fO\YV\wHUX\dN\'TCPATCF\iJC\fGHMCZN\yCHFAGCPU\yO\IC\jUJTC\wZNNZCTAXXC\yV\hH\wC\I\'MC\fAAXYO\GHTTZCMZ\kAC\yVUN\dAGJTZN\dO\NA\vAGCPHNNZCP\i\vAC\yVU\p
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225010/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVtj5pAEP7Or9jwxbu2XsSkl/RyNiGbCjUR/QBXxfEDFTy2KhhArdnsb7eziu@ifblOYsywszPP8zAzTJdZGEfV1TSJX0mNJKqqrlocFAHf2hxehc4hEDqUDA6JMHTKgQhqcoiFxSESlkkbHFLRsDlkwjZcDp5wrbZuNKht0g6HseiYMNdb0H3hpsNhJhwqXmBkmbCocxtCQes6NZyO3qCuBT5tmBR8/H1tgU5h6HQ6FAZmk8NENJvA7KZu2VBqUFhA6NoYB6UmrQOzYNTl@NcWXWrCUBaEhel0wLegZNO2bssovDc0zKYstaRmXTdo24FlC75S@OE0MN3CtSyX2rosu3yBEGHmNWCo651uCwzTtl3adGGkyxAHQSNdW4JvgaUjWUxqyixtYOitg2C6QmkVhU2mcZKRdJkqaJNggqL3VLVP3pHqo6IsQjYOyDiI7uQLuSefSeVJIWhsSOLEXz/tVfp4UCOPH4kX@cePn2vkU35D2hyzV5Sdy9Ct7jwfPW3nRehJgLvY4REMbZ80P13X1Pqkhve4enwsbUPF31M4NczByPO@yuWoLbaIvN@UZH2lMHALi21gAajFSbeCMEysXY/6baBFgK/FBuM0uJ1xmrAoI@qXJImTD2QWTbxsELLolXxPvMEoyFLCIpKFwbpk4k0e1JspsQcfgp8su7tXirGdKMpvCXrQpoyUiXa5VbdHJ@1aZLJT/Zuv6W@E3Km3YLgHZxnxSDodY0SQoKA@G3hZnPwnLcUNLTesywWsr7N9w3a5Qa14hHC59Y6WUxn7oC8no/dU1s6HYn60j44l04olewOqFyhi4bksedKd@WeygFo@8NrTntz5a8pTbDohj9wTrVzYXNdXsQSfZj4278MiYVlwlwt2fxXDoWZeRPD2FLufRWmWzAYZi6ODiRiEHkopRyKL88gTES8IeEizWkTzcJ3822CeIDirJAor/VHHnJU5VPaQsuyB1S8)

Song so far:

```
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
Never gonna give you up
```

Next line: `Never gonna let you down`

Answer (score 0):

## Day 7,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 369 bytes

```
L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\u\rZ\gN\yZN\p\pN\rPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{\rL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wLQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\gZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dLQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}RZ\(R\)
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225077/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVtb6JAEP7Or9jwpXpXGzG5JtfUS6qntQkCgp/W8QMFqptTIAvWM5v97d6g@C56L70xUYadt@fZmTFepOMorC1jHo1InXBVVZe6gEh2BYylIcCVpoCJtAQEsicglI6ARPYFpPJJNIQDDHxLNqgAImlfpw3ZFHBL5VOz0XwCxRYt0RZgdmUbKjCTLahI225T225ReIEbmFJ4M0wTWA9GoMB3vUdhbtGeDnOqwww4hZEBC2pADLEB3DKb0DaeBTUN@ZwL@vVhbKEjflumQzFIv4v6K8wc9NdpRwDHaD3wpS061MAH2pF2Ez/o/NJHV70HN/j7alETH0eZy8IykITMAUodKG/tHZ3aAjyjD14XFqvXwPpw41AHK/a6FFxqU0dfQ7JMy3CszMM/yiFtDGxDeYmsKwqbxhFPSbJIFJRpMMX7GKjqkHwitXtFmY/ZJCCTICxld1Um30j1QSEo7I1E3F@9HVSHeFAn91@IG/qHrx/r5Gvukck7Rq8qW5WhWttqPmraVgtRywrc2r4dlKHtguanq5zakNTRT6iHx5msofg7CMeCMRh53GU5b7WpLSSf1ynZUCk03JTF1mUBqMVBN4QwDKxdtvrtQosKvmQbTJLgesSYszAlaovziN@SWTh1U2/MwhF55a73I0gTwkKSjoNVSu5O79SrIbEH74KfLC2VleLajhgV1wjda1NGKkQ736qbo6N2LZKsU/2r1/Q3RG7ZmzNckbOUuCSJJ2gRcCTUZ56bRvw/cSmvcLlGXSlAfRntB7bLFWjFI4TLbXCwnCrYB8NsMgYPFe10KN4P9tEhZVoxZR8A9QxETPyepTzqzvwftABaPvDaww7c6TXlIdadkFvugFbPbK7LqzgrPkl9bN67OWdpUMoJK1@sYZ8zNyToHWP3szBJ@cxLWRTuTYQ3dpHKbCTSKLc8IvEMgfswa0Uw99fJvw3mUQUnmWRhpj/qmJM0@8zuQ856YPkL)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
```

Next line: `Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!`

My score is currently \$ 19 \frac{97}{225}\$.

Answer (score 0):

## Day 13,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 634 bytes

```
Y{\r}L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}A{B{S\i\dP}BZ{\ }ZTLZB}C{\,Z}ACBCA\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOO\iQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\uYZ\gN\yZN\p\pNYPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{YL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRC\iT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNO\iOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\F\i\gNYLZ\MN\gQ\i\f\i\cR{L\-}RRRRL\
A{\9\9Z\bLTTOPSZL\fZ\bPPY}AZLQZT\hPZ\wNOOCA\
R{\NLC\yL\uZ\cNQ\'T\.Z}H{B{\YPSC\IZ\cNQ}B\.Z}RHRHRBCB\!\
\I\fZ\IZR{TY\yC}RRR\IZ\cNQZR{\dY\iQ\k}RCRCRZA\!\
\WP\'YPZQLZSTYNQ\gPYSZTLZOL\vP
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225357/100664)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVZbb@I4FH7Pr/DmpWV3qEqlGanVdCVIS6kUEuNEWsU9PKQkgDUQUAhlkeXf3j1OUm4lsJdZI6Ic@9y@z58N83U2niU37/N0NiL3JDVN8z2QkCpbwkx1JYyVIyFUroSJohJi1ZOQKE/CQvkSMtWULemBgIiqFpdAFPdt3lKWhC9cNa2W1QSDyUfZluB2VRvqsFSPUFeMtTljjxye4QKmHIaO64LowQgMeLB7HFaU92xYcRuWAYeRA2vuwBzmTkBdC9rOk@Suo57KgVE@jCmG4ZO6HscUfhftV1h6GG7zjgwwVQ8ixWSHO/jCO4pZ@MHYZx8jH6Tdgwt8e6XcxdeResAoWFMHWdBBcNmB2ibGszmTMHB8GHRhnU@D8OHC4x4scY5DyBn37AITdanjUR0RPSiGqRjUcLrJpKOH6kimn50OY134RXMGTw4y4lIb13J3zix0wNg28j1yAptD14FRD60hfgdM2jmxjNlgNCXcwi1isX3fpcgHDDUwGqhmzk1BFpJebBA4tgVrJIgjIs0CXHGs25IQUM@C53xatfQs6@CnZbV0l7h7mPYZYfkBrC1dvPTNkQZ6R38UjPFmHvAHhYtAby33/AArjWjgacm4NrzRd5SfYYjpfJZmZLFeGDim8RSF@WKaffIruflmGKuxmMRkEieXWrQ18ju5vjMIDjEkszTKZ1@u@7hwT759JWES7U9/vye3ZYQeb5j92tiYAs2bjRWh1dhYCVq6wY3vcK@NxjZpuZrXbPTJPcZJc39ZjwJKtIVwODCHIN@3VY57ffSWkN@KkqJvVDp@tCWKtgDM6qQfhAhM3Djt9bcbrWr4lG88WcTnM85TkWTEfEzTWfqFLJNpmA3GIhmR1zQc/IizBREJycZxXjINp1fm2ZSowav4T5Fd1ozq3g4YlecI3ZGpIHXSOC7Vj6UDuVYNrdTo7Db9GyI37K0E/lYsMxKSxXyCHnGKhEZiEGaz9H/iUp3hskBdr0B9Gu1PlMsZaNVHCC@3l73LqY466OuT8XJXb3w@FG9799E@ZY1qyn4C1CMQsfCbLnmgzvKvRAW08sA37rbgPm9TmaJQQum5BXp95OY6fRXr5hdZhOK9WqUiiy9Lwmone9jlLEwIRs9R/SJZZOlykIlZsnMiBuMQqdRHIpuVngckHiFwF@ZNFczd6@S/HcyDDj5VUpWV/pFiPpXZZXYXstbA@18)
Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
We're no strangers to love
```

Next line: `You know the rules and so do I`

Answer (score 0):

## Day 17,  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), 836 bytes

```
I{\i}Y{\r}L{\o}M{\h}N{\a}O{\l}P{\e}Q{\n}S{\s}T{\t}R{H{SI\dP}HZ{\ }ZTLZH}C{\,Z}RCHCR\
R{E{F{\OM}F\-\u}E\-}RRFZRREZ\I\'\mZ\fNOOIQ\g\
\DLQZ\wPZQL\wZL\uYZ\gN\yZN\p\pNYPOC\FNG{ZON}GGGGGGGG\
\T\hPZ\w\hPPOSZLQZTMPZ\b\uSZ\gLZH{YL\uQ\d}R{HZNQ\dZH}RCRCR\
\ITZ\wD{LQ\'TZ\bPZOLQ\g}DZH{\yPN\h}R{HZ\(H\)}RCRCR\
\SLZR{\cNT\cM\y}RCRCIT\'SZS\u\cMZ\aZRZSLQ\g\
\POPNSPZR{\dD}RZ\(R\)\
\AR{NNNNN}H{RNN}HHHRRM\!\
R{\GNOIOPL}H{\(R\)ZRC}HHRZ\FI\gNYLZ\MN\gQI\fI\cR{L\-}RRRRL\
A{\9\9Z\bLTTOPSZL\fZ\bPPY}AZLQZT\hPZ\wNOOCA\
R{\NLC\yL\uZ\cNQ\'T\.Z}H{B{\YPSC\IZ\cNQ}B\.Z}RHRHRBCB\!\
\I\fZ\IZR{TY\yC}RRR\IZ\cNQZR{\dYIQ\k}RCRCRZA\!\
\[I\gQLYPZP\vPY\yT\hIQ\gZ\bP\fLYPZT\hISZOIQP\]\
\WP\'YPZQLZSTYNQ\gPYSZTLZOL\vP\
\YL\uZ\kQL\wZT\hPZY\uOPSZNQ\dZSLZ\dLZ\I\
\AZ\f\uOOZ\cL\m\mIT\mPQT\'SZ\w\hNTZ\I\'\mZT\hIQ\kIQ\gZL\f\
\YL\uZ\wL\uO\dQ\'TZ\gPTZT\hISZ\fYL\mZNQ\yZLT\hPYZ\g\u\y
```

[Previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225660/100664)

Song so far:

```
side to side, side, side to side
Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh Oh-u-Oh-u-Oh-u I'm falling
Don we now our gay apparel, Fa la la la la la la la la
The wheels on the bus go round and round, round and round, round and round
It won't be long yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah), yeah (yeah)
So catchy, catchy, it's such a catchy song
Please don't be long (don't be long)
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah!
(Galileo) Galileo, (Galileo) Galileo, Galileo Figaro Magnifico-o-o-o-o
99 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer
No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can. No, you can't. Yes, I can, Yes, I can!
If I try, try, try, I can drink, drink, drink 99 bottles of beer!
[ignore everything before this line]
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
```

[Try it online](https://deadfish.surge.sh/splinter#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)

Next line: `I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling`